# What are all the common undefined behaviours that a C++ programmer should know about?

Tags: c++, undefined, undefined-behavior, c++-faq

What are all the common undefined behaviours that a C++ programmer should know about?

Say, like:

```
a[i] = i++;
```

Comment: Are you sure. That looks well defined.

Comment: 6.2.2 Evaluation Order [expr.evaluation] in The C++ programming language say so.I dont have any other reference

Comment: He's right.. just looked at 6.2.2 in The C++ Programming Language and it says v[i] = i++ is undefined

Comment: I would imagine because the the comiler make execute the i++ before or after calculating the memory location of v[i]. sure, i is always going to be assigned there. but it could write to either v[i] or v[i+1] depending on order of operations..

Comment: Martin, the variable will get updated some time after it is read on the right side. That may before or after the variable is read to evaluate the left side.

Comment: @Rob: isn't that what I had just said?

Comment: As an example: it could either go: (psuedo asm): "lea edi, [v + i]; mov [edi], i; inc i" or "mov eax, i; inc i; lea edi, [v + i]; mov [edi], eax" – Evan Teran

Comment: All that The C++ Programming Language says is "The order of operations of subexpressions within an expression is undefined. In particular, you cannot assume that the expression is evaluated left to right."

Comment: OK. After reading n2521 Section 5.2.6 I think I have it. See me answer below.

Comment: It seems to be a rite-of-passage these days for a moderator to force-close a popular question, even ones (like this one) that are gray-area *(and thus should be decided by the community at large, not a single overzealous moderator)*.

Comment: Exactly, this seems to me a perfect example of good contribution to SO.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

#### Pointer

- Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer
- Dereferencing a pointer returned by a "new" allocation of size zero
- Using pointers to objects whose lifetime has ended (for instance, stack allocated objects or deleted objects)
- Dereferencing  a pointer that has not yet been definitely initialized
- Performing pointer arithmetic that yields a result outside the boundaries (either above or below) of an array.
- Dereferencing the pointer at a location beyond the end of an array.
- Converting pointers to objects of incompatible types
- [Using `memcpy` to copy overlapping buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11211519/241536).

#### Buffer overflows

- Reading or writing to an object or array at an offset that is negative, or beyond the size of that object (stack/heap overflow)

#### Integer Overflows

- Signed integer overflow
- Evaluating an expression that is not mathematically defined
- Left-shifting values by a negative amount (right shifts by negative amounts are implementation defined)
- Shifting values by an amount greater than or equal to the number of bits in the number (e.g. `int64_t i = 1; i <<= 72` is undefined)

#### Types, Cast and Const

- Casting a numeric value into a value that can't be represented by the target type (either directly or via static_cast)
- Using an automatic variable before it has been definitely assigned (e.g., `int i; i++; cout << i;`)
- Using the value of any object of type other than `volatile` or `sig_atomic_t` at the receipt of a signal
- Attempting to modify a string literal or any other const object during its lifetime
- Concatenating a narrow with a wide string literal during preprocessing

#### Function and Template

- Not returning a value from a value-returning function (directly or by flowing off from a try-block)
- Multiple different definitions for the same entity (class, template, enumeration, inline function, static member function, etc.)
- Infinite recursion in the instantiation of templates
- Calling a function using different parameters or linkage to the parameters and linkage that the function is defined as using.

#### OOP

- Cascading destructions of objects with static storage duration
- The result of assigning to partially overlapping objects
- Recursively re-entering a function during the initialization of its static objects
- Making virtual function calls to pure virtual functions of an object from its constructor or destructor
- Referring to nonstatic members of objects that have not been constructed or have already been destructed

#### Source file and Preprocessing

- A non-empty source file that doesn't end with a newline, or ends with a backslash (prior to C++11)
- A backslash followed by a character that is not part of the specified escape codes in a character or string constant (this is implementation-defined in C++11).
- Exceeding implementation limits (number of nested blocks, number of functions in a program, available stack space ...)
- Preprocessor numeric values that can't be represented by a `long int`
- Preprocessing directive on the left side of a function-like macro definition
- Dynamically generating the defined token in a `#if` expression

#### To be classified

- Calling exit during the destruction of a program with static storage duration

Comment: Hm...  NaN (x / 0) and Infinity (0 / 0) were covered by the IEE 754, if C++ was designed later, why does it record x / 0 as  undefined?

Comment: Re: "A backslash followed by a character that is not part of the specified escape codes in a character or string constant." That's UB in C89 (§3.1.3.4) and C++03 (which incorporates C89), but not in C99.  C99 says that "the result is not a token and a diagnostic is required" (§6.4.4.4).  Presumably C++0x (which incorporates C89) will be the same.

Comment: The C99 standard has a list of undefined behaviors in appendix J.2. It would take some work to adapt this list to C++. You'd have to change the references to the correct C++ clauses rather than the C99 clauses, remove anything irrelevant, and also check whether all those things really are undefined in C++ as well as C. But it provides a start.

Comment: Quite a useful and impressive list.  I need to add this one, as I was just burnt by it: enum size is not defined; it only needs to be large enough to contain an int.  "Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined, but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration."

Comment: @new123456 - not all floating point units are IEE754 compatible. If C++ required IEE754 compliance, compilers would need to test and handle the case where the RHS is zero via an explicit check. By making the behaviour undefined, the compiler can avoid that overhead by saying "if you use a non IEE754 FPU, you won't get IEEE754 FPU behaviour".

Comment: "Shifting values by an amount greater than the log2-size of the container (e.g. __int64 i = (37 << 72) is undefined)". This is a bit misleading, and not always true. That is only undefined behavior if `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT <= 72` is true. The object you put the result of `37 << 72` in is irrelevant, the expression itself is what invokes undefined behavior. For instance, `uint8_t n = (1 << 15);` is perfectly fine. You first evaluate `1 << 15`, which is 2**15. The result is the then implicitly cast from an `int` to a `uint8_t`, which means that `n == 0` (due to modular arithmetic)

Comment: "Evaluating an expression whose result is not in the range of the corresponding types" .... integer overflow is well-defined for UNSIGNED integral types, just not signed ones.

Comment: I was just about to make the same comment as @nacitarsevaht.

Answer (score 31):

The order that function parameters are evaluated is ***unspecified* behavior**. (This won't make your program crash, explode, or order pizza... unlike ***undefined* behavior**.)

The only requirement is that all parameters must be fully evaluated before the function is called.

---

This:

```
// The simple obvious one.
callFunc(getA(),getB());
```

Can be equivalent to this:

```
int a = getA();
int b = getB();
callFunc(a,b);
```

Or this:

```
int b = getB();
int a = getA();
callFunc(a,b);
```

It can be either; it's up to the compiler. The result can matter, depending on the side effects.

Comment: The order is unspecified, not undefined.

Comment: I hate this one :) I lost a day of work once tracking down one of these cases... anyways learned my lesson and haven't fallen again fortunately

Comment: @Rob: I would argue with you about the change in meaning here, but I know the standards committee is very picky on the exact definition of these two words. So I'll just change it :-)

Comment: I got lucky on this one.  I got bitten by it when I was in college and had a professor who took one look at it and told me my problem in about 5 seconds.  No telling how much time I would have wasted debugging otherwise.

Answer (score 27):

The compiler is free to re-order the evaluation parts of an expression (assuming the meaning is unchanged).

From the original question:

```
a[i] = i++;

// This expression has three parts:
(a) a[i]
(b) i++
(c) Assign (b) to (a)

// (c) is guaranteed to happen after (a) and (b)
// But (a) and (b) can be done in either order.
// See n2521 Section 5.17
// (b) increments i but returns the original value.
// See n2521 Section 5.2.6
// Thus this expression can be written as:

int rhs  = i++;
int lhs& = a[i];
lhs = rhs;

// or
int lhs& = a[i];
int rhs  = i++;
lhs = rhs;
```

Double Checked locking.
And one easy mistake to make.

```
A* a = new A("plop");

// Looks simple enough.
// But this can be split into three parts.
(a) allocate Memory
(b) Call constructor
(c) Assign value to 'a'

// No problem here:
// The compiler is allowed to do this:
(a) allocate Memory
(c) Assign value to 'a'
(b) Call constructor.
// This is because the whole thing is between two sequence points.

// So what is the big deal.
// Simple Double checked lock. (I know there are many other problems with this).
if (a == null) // (Point B)
{
    Lock   lock(mutex);
    if (a == null)
    {
        a = new A("Plop");  // (Point A).
    }
}
a->doStuff();

// Think of this situation.
// Thread 1: Reaches point A. Executes (a)(c)
// Thread 1: Is about to do (b) and gets unscheduled.
// Thread 2: Reaches point B. It can now skip the if block
//           Remember (c) has been done thus 'a' is not NULL.
//           But the memory has not been initialized.
//           Thread 2 now executes doStuff() on an uninitialized variable.

// The solution to this problem is to move the assignment of 'a'
// To the other side of the sequence point.
if (a == null) // (Point B)
{
    Lock   lock(mutex);
    if (a == null)
    {
        A* tmp = new A("Plop");  // (Point A).
        a = tmp;
    }
}
a->doStuff();

// Of course there are still other problems because of C++ support for
// threads. But hopefully these are addresses in the next standard.
```

Comment: what is mean by sequence point?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Comment: Ooh... that's nasty, especially since I've seen that exact structure recommended in Java

Comment: Note that some compilers do define the behaviour in this situation.  In VC++ 2005+, for example, if a is volatile, the needed memory bariers are set up to prevent instruction reordering so that double-checked locking works.

Comment: Martin York: <i>// (c) is guaranteed to happen after (a) and (b)</i> Is it?  Admittedly in that particular example the only scenario where it could matter would be if 'i' was a volatile variable mapped to a hardware register, and a[i] (old value of 'i') was aliased to it, but is there any guarantee that the increment will happen before a sequence point?

Comment: @supercat: Yes it is guaranteed. Both sides of the `=` must be evaluated before it can be evaluated.

Comment: @Martin York: The expression "i=i++;" is commonly given as an example of undefined behavior in C (I know the behavior is defined in some other languages like Java).  If the side effects of the increment are not guaranteed to be over and done with by the time an "i=i++;" assignment occurs, why would they be guaranteed to be complete by the time "a[i]=i++;" occurs?

Comment: @supercat: OK I see where you are coming from. You are correct the effect of the operator ++ (on i) is not guaranteed to be done by that point.

Comment: `a[i] = i++;` is undefined behavior anyway. The compiler is free to do more than just reorder it, it can ignore it or do the thing with the nose. `i` is modified on the RHS, and on the LHS it is read other than for the purpose of determining the value to be written. Game over (unless `i` is a class type with `operator++` overload, then any object modifications inside that overload are safely wrapped in sequence points, and it's just unspecified order not UB).

Comment: @Steve: Absolutely correct. I was just trying to explain why it needs to be undefined (and some probable implementation explanations).

Comment: @Martin: not sure I agree that this explains why it has to be undefined. There are other situations in which the order of operations is unspecified, without invoking UB. For example in the case I mentioned where `i` is a class type that imitates an integer with suitable `operator++(int)` and `operator int()`, your two either/or options are both still possible, but there's no UB. That said, maybe in saying "undefined behavior", the questioner means any situation that behavior isn't completely nailed down, as opposed to the standard's definition of UB.

Comment: Your double-checked lock example is *vicious*. ಥ_ಥ

Comment: Hi, I was wandering what other problems for the second version of sigleton implementation. Seems like it is perfect.

Comment: @zoujyjs: If you want to create a singelton with pointers you are doing it wrong. See [C++ Singleton design pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/14065)

Comment: Yeah, I read about that also in "*Effective C++*" Item 04. And that one is guaranteed thread-safe after c++0x. But why not pointers? And if not what if I just return the dereference of the pointers? Because singleton is supposed to be there all through the life of a process, I didn't need to destory it with a explicit pointer.

Comment: Particularly, I want to know if the code above is considered a fairly good implementation of the DCLP.

Comment: @zoujyjs: No its not good in C++03. There are issues with threading and double checked locking in C++ that makes it impossible to do correctly; there is a famous paper by Sutter on it. I believe it is fixed for C++11 but you will need to use new features not documented here.

Comment: @zoujyjs: Here it is: [C++ and The Perils of Double-Checked Locking](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c-and-the-perils-of-double-checked-locki/184405726) Actually by Meyers and Alexandrescu

Answer (score 5):

Assigning to a constant after stripping `const`ness using `const_cast<>`:

```
const int i = 10; 
int *p =  const_cast<int*>( &i );
*p = 1234; //Undefined
```

Answer (score 5):

My favourite is "Infinite recursion in the instantiation of templates" because I believe it's the only one where the undefined behaviour occurs at compile time.

Comment: Done this before, but I don't see how its undefined. Its quite obvious your doing an infinite recursion in afterthought.

Comment: The problem is that the compiler cannot examine your code and decide precisely whether it will suffer from infinite recursion or not. It's an instance of the halting problem. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235984/the-halting-problem-in-the-field#334759

Comment: Yeah its definitely a halting problem

Comment: it made my system crash because of swapping caused by too little memory.

Comment: Preprocessor constants that don't fit into an int is also compile time.

Answer (score 5):

Besides **undefined behaviour**, there is also the equally nasty **implementation-defined behaviour**.

Undefined behaviour occurs when a program does something the result of which is not specified by the standard.

Implementation-defined behaviour is an action by a program the result of which is not defined by the standard, but which the implementation is required to document. An example is "Multibyte character literals", from Stack Overflow question *[Is there a C compiler that fails to compile this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328215)*.

Implementation-defined behaviour only bites you when you start porting (but upgrading to new version of compiler is also porting!)

Answer (score 4):

Variables may only be updated once in an expression (technically once between sequence points).

```
int i =1;
i = ++i;

// Undefined. Assignment to 'i' twice in the same expression.
```

Comment: Infact _at least_ once between two sequence points.

Comment: @Prasoon: I think you meant : *at most* once between two sequence points. :-)

Answer (score 3):

A basic understanding of the various environmental limits. The full list is in section 5.2.4.1 of the C specification. Here are a few;

- 127 parameters in one function deﬁnition
- 127 arguments in one function call
- 127 parameters in one macro deﬁnition
- 127 arguments in one macro invocation
- 4095 characters in a logical source line
- 4095 characters in a character string
  literal or wide string literal (after
  concatenation)
- 65535 bytes in an
  object (in a hosted environment only)
- 15nesting levels for #includedﬁles
- 1023 case labels for a switch
  statement (excluding those for
  anynested switch statements)

I was actually a bit surprised at the limit of 1023 case labels for a switch statement, I can forsee that being exceeded for generated code/lex/parsers fairly easially.

If these limits are exceeded, you have undefined behavior (crashes, security flaws, etc...).

Right, I know this is from the C specification, but C++ shares these basic supports.

Comment: If you hit these limits, you've got more problems than undefined behavior.

Comment: You could EASILY exceed 65535 bytes in an object, such as an STD::vector

Answer (score 2):

The only type for which C++ guarantees a size is `char`. And the size is 1. The size of all other types is platform dependent.

Comment: Isn't that what <cstdint> is for? It defines types such as uint16_6 et cetera.

Comment: Yes, but the size of most types, say long, is not well defined.

Comment: also cstdint isn't part of the current c++ standard yet. see boost/stdint.hpp for a currently portable solution.

Comment: That's not undefined behaviour. The standard says that conforming platform defines the sizes, rather than the standard defining them.

Comment: Also not that the standard does not define how much 1 byte is. It is at least 8 bits, but anything above that is allowed, so a C++-byte is not necessarily equal to a real life byte / anyways, I vote you up as this does not deserve a down-vote.

Comment: @JaredPar:  This is not strictly true.  A `long` is [guaranteed to be at least 32 bits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329777/is-long-guaranteed-to-be-at-least-32-bits).

Comment: @JohnDibling i looked through that post and the linked ones but I couldn't find a definitive source for it being 32 bits. One user proclaimed such but there was no reference to a spec line which made the garuantee

Comment: @JaredPar: It's a complex post with a lot of threads of conversation, so I summed it all up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4337544/241536).  The bottom line is this: "5. In order to represent -2147483647 and +2147483647 in binary, you need 32 bits."

Comment: For similar reasons, an `int` is at least 16 bits, and a `long long` is at least 64 (added to the standard in C++11).

Answer (score 2):

Namespace-level objects in a different compilation units should never depend on each other for initialization, because their initialization order is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Using `memcpy` to copy between overlapping memory regions.  For example:

```
char a[256] = {};
memcpy(a, a, sizeof(a));
```

The behavior is undefined according to the C Standard, which is subsumed by the C++03 Standard.

### 7.21.2.1 The memcpy function

> Synopsis
>
> 1/ #include  void *memcpy(void * restrict s1, const
>   void * restrict s2, size_t n);
>
> Description
>
> 2/ The memcpy function
>   copies n characters from the object pointed to by s2 into the object
>   pointed to by s1. If copying takes place between objects that overlap,
>   the behavior is undefined. Returns 3 The memcpy function returns the
>   value of s1.

### 7.21.2.2 The memmove function

> Synopsis
>
> 1 #include  void *memmove(void *s1, const void *s2, size_t
>   n);
>
> Description
>
> 2 The memmove function copies n characters from the object pointed to
>   by s2 into the object pointed to by s1. Copying takes place as if the
>   n characters from the object pointed to by s2 are first copied into a
>   temporary array of n characters that does not overlap the objects
>   pointed to by s1 and s2, and then the n characters from the temporary
>   array are copied into the object pointed to by s1. Returns
>
> 3 The memmove function returns the value of s1.