# How to use enum in C

Tags: c, enums, linked-list

Basically we have to implement a queue (linked list) for a restaurant waiting queue.

We get extra points for using `enum` but I've never used it before. I'm wondering does this look right how I am using it? I have looked it up but haven't seen any examples using linked lists.

Here is the instructions for our structure:

> When writing your code, you MUST create a C struct for the nodes in the linked list of the wait list. These data items must include the following (and may include others if needed).
>
> - the name of the group
> - the integer variable specifying the size of the group (number of people in the group)
> - the in-restaurant status (extra points for using an enum!)
> - a pointer to the next node in the list
>
> The restaurant status is walk-in or call-in (call ahead of time to put name on waiting list)

Here's the structure of mine:

```
typedef struct restaurant
{
    char name[30];
    int groupSize;
    enum status{call, wait};
    struct restaurant *nextNode;
}list;
```

I'm asking because I get this warning when I compile:

> ```
> lab6.c:11:28: warning: declaration does not declare anything [enabled by default]
> ```

Comment: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Enum.html

Comment: What exactly is your question? Don't just throw your assignment at people with build errors you're getting. Pinpoint a single issue where you're stuck, then ask for help.

Comment: @juice - I honestly think you've asked a fair question, and that you've sincerely done due diligence trying to answer it yourself.  Take heart in the old "Latin" phrase ["illegitimi non carborundum"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illegitimi_non_carborundum) ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your struct typedef is basically saying "If I had a "status" field in my record, it could have the value "call" or the value "wait".  The warning is basically saying "you never allocated a field".

Possible change:

```
enum status {CALL, WAIT};

typedef struct restaurant
{
    char name[30];
    int groupSize;
    enum status my_status;
    struct restaurant *nextNode;
}list;
```

Here's more info:

- [How to define an enumerated type (enum) in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102542/how-to-define-an-enumerated-type-enum-in-c)

Comment: What's the `= CALL` notation?  Are you perhaps confusing C and C++?

Comment: My bad.  Corrected.  I just wanted to say that I generally prefer enum values like "CALL" or "WAIT" than lower-case "call" or "wait".  IMHO...

Comment: Thanks for the sound advice. I assume people are aggressive on here because some posters are asking for StackOverflow users to do their homework. I'm not trying to do that. People on here tend to forget this site can be used for a very useful learning tool. I've stated that I looked up enum but no clear cut examples for linked lists. Thanks again. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Your `enum` must either be declared outside the structure:

```
enum Status {call, wait};

typedef struct restaurant
{
    char name[30];
    int groupSize;
    struct restaurant *nextNode;
} list;
```

or must declare a member of that type inside the structure:

```
typedef struct restaurant
{
    char name[30];
    int groupSize;
    enum Status {call, wait} status;
    struct restaurant *nextNode;
} list;
```

or both:

```
enum Status {call, wait};

typedef struct restaurant
{
    char name[30];
    int groupSize;
    enum Status status;
    struct restaurant *nextNode;
} list;
```

You could create a typedef for the `enum Status` too.  And since the tags (such as `Status` in `enum Status`) are in a different namespace from structure members, you could actually use:

```
enum status {call, wait} status;
```

and the compiler won't be confused but you might well be.

Very often, people write enumeration constants in ALL_CAPS.  This is partly a hangover from the days of using `#define WAIT 0` and `#define CALL 1` instead of `enum Status { WAIT, CALL };`.

Comment: Perhaps you meant holdover, not hangover.

Comment: No; it's a hangover — people get headaches from it all.