# How to initialize an enum?

Tags: c, function, enums

```
typedef enum
{
    HEARTS = 0, 
    SPADES, 
    DIAMONDS, 
    CLUBS
}Suits; //here HEARTS = 0, SPADES = 1, DIAMONDS = 2, and CLUBS = 3  

int main()
{
    Suits hand;
    play(hand);
    return 0;
}

void play(Suits hand)
{
    printf("Testing.\n");
}
```

When I compile something similar to this, the compiler gives me the error: implicit declaration of function 'play' and warning: 'menu' may be used uninitialized in this function. How can I fix these problems?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102542/how-to-define-an-enumerated-type-enum-in-c

Comment: That didn't solve my problem. I'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: The error is nothing to do with the enum, see ring0 answer below

Comment: This has nothing to do with enums, please google your error message before whining to SO about it, and "menu" doesn't even appear in your code so I don't very well know what you expect us to do about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the compiler meets the call to *play* it doesn't know that function yet, since it's declared below. Thus the warning. Just move the declaration before *main*

```
typedef enum{HEARTS = 0, SPADES, DIAMONDS, CLUBS}Suits; //here HEARTS = 0, SPADES = 1, DIAMONDS = 2, and CLUBS = 3  

void play(Suits hand)
{
  printf("Testing.\n");
}

int main()
{
  Suits hand;
  play(hand);
  return 0;
}
```

To remove the 2nd warning, you declare

```
Suits hand;
```

but *hand* is not initialized yet, thus the compiler warns you that the value you provide to the function *play* is not initialized.

Just set a value for *hand* :

```
Suits hand = SPADES;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've declared it above, `Suits` defines a type that can only contain one of HEARTS, SPADES, DIAMONDS, CLUBS. So when you declare `hand` as a `Suit` type, it can take values that you defined in your enum.

Try defining `hand` as a card type:

```
hand = SPADES;
```

then call play(hand).

Think of it similarly to declaring an `int`.

```
int x;
```

`x` is of an integer type and must contain values defined by this type. If you call a function

```
someFunc (x);
```

without intializing `x`, you'll get undefined behaviour.

EDIT:
Also, put the definition of your `play` function above `main` (after the enum definition). Either that, or you need to declare your function above `main`:

```
void play(Suits hand);
```

Otherwise, `main` doesn't know what "play" refers to since the definition comes after it.