# C, enum within struct, error C2016, header file

Tags: c, header-files

Got it working, thanks all ;]

code

```
enum genre {A, B, C, D, E};

struct recipe
{
    genre category;
    char name[50];
    char ingredients[50]; 
    char instruction[1000];
};


void menu();
void file_check(char *name);
```

errors:

```
error C2016: C requires that a struct or union has at least one member
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'genre'
error C2059: syntax error : '}'
```

This is my header file. I can't figure out what compiler want from me :( I thought it would work this way

Comment: you presume you are compiling C with some kind of a C++ compiler. In C you _need_ the {struct,union,enum} tag, when referring to the `genre` name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102542/how-to-define-an-enumerated-type-enum-in-c

Comment: I suggest you to see how to typedef an enumeration. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102542/how-to-define-an-enumerated-type-enum-in-c

Comment: Same as with `struct`.

Comment: Also note that char[1000] is too small for storing a recipe (at least for the paella) :P

Comment: Thanks all for help ;]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C requires you to use:

```
enum genre category;
```

instead of

```
genre category;
```

To use `genre category` declaration, you'd need to `typedef`:

```
typedef enum {A, B, C, D, E} genre;
```

instead of

```
enum genre {A, B, C, D, E};
```

Comment: that's a clear answer,struct contains variable declarations `genre category;` is not the proper declaration

Answer (score 0):

C language requires that an identifier of `struct/enum/union` type, have its type by your left-side in each place you want to use it. For avoid typying this each time, you can use typedef keyword.