# Modifying a macro's name in code

Tags: c

I feel like this is something simple and i am just missing something but i am looking to have a function that check values of a bunch of values that are part of predefined macros.
The function goes something like:

```
for (i=0  i <100...
if namei_int ==0
{
code
}
```

How to i modify that macro calls name? with it being name0_int name1_int...

if there even is a way. so far i have made a bunch of if and case statements, however, i assume there is an easier way of doing this.

I have looked into making a #define array[100] = [name0_int,name2_int....]

Comment: I think you are looking for this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102542/how-to-define-an-enumerated-type-enum-in-c

Comment: To what do these `name<i>_int` macros expand?

Comment: I think you want macro token concatenation operator: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros aren't expanded at runtime, they make textual changes to the code before they reach the compiler.  You can use the concatenation operator to get a macro that does what you want:

```
#define GET_NAME_INT(x) name ## x ## _int
GET_NAME_INT(0) /* this is name0_int */
GET_NAME_INT(1) /* this is name1_int */
```

But you can't loop over this to get what you want -- using the variable i expands to namei_int at compilation time. You can't put macros in arrays either, they are just not the sort of things that exist at runtime.

You can, however, put function pointers into arrays, and I would think that is generally what you want in this case.  i.e.:

```
struct my_args {int x, y, z};
void function1(struct my_args *);
void function2(struct my_args *);
void function3(struct my_args *);
void function4(struct my_args *);

...
int i;
void (*my_funcs)(struct my_args *)[] = {function1, function2, function3, function4};
struct my_args args= {0, 1, 50};

for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    my_funcs[i](&args);
}
```

If you really want to use macros, you can eliminate rewriting the "code" part by pulling it out into a function call, (or, if you prefer, a macro.)  I.e.:

```
    /* just an example, the do while is so you can put a ';' after and 
     * make it look like a statement */

    #define DO_STUFF do{j += ((x + y - 4) / 17 + i)}while(0)

    i = 0;
    if (name0_int == 0)
         DO_STUFF;
    i++;
    if (name1_int == 0)
         DO_STUFF;
    i++;
    if (name2_int == 0)
         DO_STUFF;
```

Debugging macro code like this can be a real chore, If the point of using macros is performance, then you could consider inlined functions, when you can turn off the optomizations if you have to crawl through a debugger.