# While writing a code in C error : expected an identifier while defining enum

Tags: c

while coding in C, for the below syntax, I receive an error: expected an identifier, please let me know where am I going wrong ? Thank you.

```
enum a { 
    false;   // error : expected an identifier
    true;   // // error : expected an identifier
 };

typedef enum a a;
```

Comment: Reason for that is that you use `a` twice in your definition...

Comment: @arc_lupus: no, this is allowed in C.

Comment: You shouldn't use names that are reserved by the standard libraries. `false` and `true` are already defined by `stdbool.h`, so you shouldn't use those names.

Comment: @Lundin: But only if `stdbool.h` is `#include`ed. Otherwise they are valid names in C - but not in C++ (maybe he uses a C++ compiler?). OP should provide the context.

Answer (score 3):

Use comma after enum constant.

```
enum a { 
    false,
    true
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be a comma after `false`, not a semicolon.

And a comma after `true` is optional.

You don't even need to Google for it, just search this site. E.g. [How to define an enumerated type (enum) in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102542/how-to-define-an-enumerated-type-enum-in-c#1102556)

Comment: Note that trailing comma in an enum is only optional since C99. Earlier, they weren't allowed. It was an inconsistency in the C language which was corrected with C99.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef enum a { 
    false,
    true
} a;
```

is a succinct way of doing this. Note the comma after `false`, and the use of `typedef`.

I wouldn't recommend using `false` and `true` as enumerated names though; especially if you intend to port your code to C++.