# What's the best way to declare an enum variable in C?

Tags: c, variables, enums

This question arises from an old question:

[How to define an enumerated type (enum) in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1102542/5399734)

Answers below that question are just conflicting with each other. For example, [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1102556/5399734) said "You need to use `typedef`", [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1104903/5399734) argued "You don't need a `typedef`", a comment under which wrote "You cannot use `enum strategy { ... };` in C -- you can and should do it in C++ though." This really confuses me. What's more, that OP's code compiles without even warnings using clang on all my computers.

So, my question is: In C, what's the best practice to use enum variables?

Comment: Doesn't [Johannes Schaub's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1104903/1392132) explain this?

Comment: @5gon12eder Yes, that's what the "another" refers to. But a comment below it says we cannot write this in C, as mentioned in my question.

Comment: That comment is just wrong.

Comment: To quote from Wikipedia: "The original K&R dialect of the C programming language did not have enumerated types, but they were added in the ANSI standard for C, which became C89."

Comment: @Amnon You mean `C89 = ANSI C + enum type` ?

Comment: @sun qingyao  more like `C89 = K&R + enum type + other stuff I don't know about...`  :-)

Comment: C89 adds *far* more to K&R than just `enum` types.  Function prototypes and ANSI-style function definitions are probably the most famous ones.  These days, I suspect that some C programmers don't even realize there is an alternative style of function definition.

Comment: Isn't K&R style removed in newer standards ?!!

Comment: @sunqingyao, nope.  K&R-style function definitions are still in the latest C standard, C2011.  I'm inclined to suppose that they are retained mostly for the sake of legacy code.

Answer (score 2):

C has two namespaces, one for variables and functions and another for things like `enum`s and `struct`s. Let's call the second one the `enum` namespace.

When you declare an `enum` like `enum Foo {Bar1, Bar2};`, `Foo`, and the enumeration constants will be put into the `enum` namespace.

This means that you have to use the `enum` prefix whenever you want to use that enumeration. Which is a lot of inconvenient typing! (Out of interest, the same applies to `struct`).

Fortunately C allows you to *borrow* things from the `enum` namespace, so they appear in the variable and function namespace too. You do that using a `typedef`:

`typedef enum Foo {Bar1, Bar2} Foo;`

The first `Foo` is its name in the `enum` namespace, the second `Foo` is its name in the function and variable namespace.

You don't need to do this in C++: unless you use `namespace` explicitly, everything is in the *global* namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Despite its large number of votes and its highly upvoted answers, the question you reference is based on a completely false premise.  It asserts that this code is erroneous in C:

```
enum {RANDOM, IMMEDIATE, SEARCH} strategy;
strategy = IMMEDIATE;
```

In fact, however, that code is perfectly fine in C89, C99, and C2011.  It declares variable `strategy` to be of an anonymous enumerated type with the given enumeration constants, and it initializes that variable to one of the three values defined for its type.  The error messages the OP of that question reported may have been emitted by a non-conforming compiler, or perhaps there was more to the story than that OP presented.

On the other hand, that form of variable declaration is of comparatively little practical use, because no other object can be declared to have the same type as the variable declared there.  There are two alternatives for declaring an enumerated *type* so that it can be used in multiple declarations:

1. Declare the type with a tag: `enum strategy_tag {RANDOM, IMMEDIATE, SEARCH} /* ... */ ;`
2. Use a `typedef` to name the type: `typedef enum {RANDOM, IMMEDIATE, SEARCH} strategy_type;`

How you then refer to the type depends on which form you used.  If you declare the type as a tagged enum, then you can use it in declarations by referencing the tag:

```
enum strategy_tag my_strategy = RANDOM;
```

.  If you declare the type as a `typedef`'d name then you use the defined name as the type name

```
strategy_type my_strategy = IMMEDIATE;
```

.  These are not exclusive; you can both tag an `enum` and declare a `typedef` for it, in separate statements ...

```
enum strategy_tag {RANDOM, IMMEDIATE, SEARCH};
typedef enum strategy_tag strategy_type;
```

... or even in one ...

```
typedef enum strategy_tag {RANDOM, IMMEDIATE, SEARCH} strategy_type;
```

.  If you use both forms of type declaration then you can use either or both forms of type specifier in variable declarations.

Additionally, be aware that the namespaces for enum tags, type names, and variable names are all separate, so although it might be a bit confusing, you can do this:

```
typedef enum strategy {RANDOM, IMMEDIATE, SEARCH} strategy;
strategy strategy = RANDOM;
enum strategy strategy2 = strategy;
```

---

As for which way is *best*, the answer is not so clear.  If you have an established set of coding conventions that address this question then of course it is best to follow the conventions.  If not then you can choose, but be consistent, at least within any given project.  I tend to think that `typedef`s are overused in general, but using then to name `enum`s is one of the uses I think makes sense.  If you do that, however, then I suggest *not* declaring tags for `typedef`'d `enum`s -- since you're after consistency, explicitly providing a mechanism for *in*consistency is counterproductive.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit subjective, but there is an industry de facto standard in C and C++ both. It goes:

If you need to declare instances (variables) of the type, then you should keep type definitions completely separate from the variable declarations.

When you mix them up, the code gets confusing to read. This goes for enums and all other types. Example:

```
typedef enum
{
  THIS,
  THAT
} mytype_t;

...

mytype_t variable;
```

---

However, as a special case: if you don't intend to declare any variables of a certain type, but just want a more readable way than `#define` to enumerate several integer constants belonging to the same group, then it is fine to do like this:

```
enum
{
  THIS_CONSTANT = 123,
  THAT_CONSTANT = 567
};

...

int something = THIS_CONSTANT + THAT_CONSTANT;
```

Comment: Using a `_t` as your own type, and from one of the most respected contributors on this site. Naughty step for you.

Comment: @Bathsheba Why? It is also de facto industry standard naming convention and there is nothing in the C standard disallowing it, quite the contrary. See 7.1.3 regarding what's not allowed. An underscore at the beginning of an identifier is what you should watch out for.

Comment: @Bathsheba Aah I understand where you got that idea from. From POSIX. I really couldn't care less, all I care about is the C standard. If POSIX chose to deviate from the C standard or add non-standard restrictions, then that's their problem, not mine. I never work with POSIX systems, personally.