# error C2071 Illegal storage class, definig enum type in C

Tags: c, struct, enums

I am trying to define an enum struct in C as following. I get the error ** Illegal storage class**.

```
typedef struct
{
  typedef enum 
  {
    Gerade,
    Gerade_penta,
    Gerade_3D,
    Koppler,
    Krumm,
    Schraeg,
    SForm,
    SForm2,
    SForm2_3D,
    Tapered     
  } wg_type;

  double start; double end;
  double xsk; double xek; 
  double xsk2; double xek2;
   ...
} My_Struct;
```

I have also tried following ways. but still the same problem. based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102542/how-to-define-an-enumerated-type-enum-in-c).

```
enum wg_type {...};
```

Am I missing something? Can anybody help me solve the problem?

Comment: You can't use typedef like that in a struct. Move the enum out of the struct

Comment: How about the second way? where it is just an enum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
typedef enum 
{
    Gerade,
    Gerade_penta,
    Gerade_3D,
    Koppler,
    Krumm,
    Schraeg,
    SForm,
    SForm2,
    SForm2_3D,
    Tapered     
} My_Enum;

typedef struct
{
    My_Enum my_enum;

    double start; double end;
    double xsk; double xek; 
    double xsk2; double xek2;
    ...
} My_Struct;
```

You *can* declare an enum in a struct like this:

```
struct My_Struct
{
    enum {X, Y, Z} my_enum;
    ...
};
```

Generally you want it out of the struct though, because declaring it in the struct makes no difference, and makes it less readable

Comment: It solved the problem. But is it in general not possible to define **enum** in a **struct**?