# #define array format in c

Tags: c, format

I have a header file in which I create a map array

`#define MAP { {WALL,WALL,WALL,WALL,WALL,WALL,WALL,WALL,WALL,WALL,WALL,WALL}, {WALL,START,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,WALL,END,EMPTY,EMPTY,WALL} }`

however I'm getting the error: `expected expression before"{" token`

May somebody help me understand why and how to correct it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102542/how-to-define-an-enumerated-type-enum-in-c

Comment: You need to add "\" to the end of the first line

Comment: A newline ends a macro definition unless the line ends with a continuation character, i.e. \

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using multi-lines with `#define` you need to add the escape character `\`. So:

```
#define MAP { {WALL,WALL,WALL,WALL,WALL,WALL,WALL,WALL,WALL,WALL,WALL,WALL}, \
     {WALL,START,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,WALL,END,EMPTY,EMPTY,WALL} }
```

Otherwise the compiler thinks the next line doesn't belong to the macro.