# How to use different enums that have the same names in C

Tags: c, enums

I have in one library, `liba`, an [enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102542/how-to-define-an-enumerated-type-enum-in-c) like this:

```
typedef enum LIB_A_ENUM {
  FOO,
  BAR
} LIB_A_ENUM
```

In `libb` I have another enum:

```
typedef enum LIB_B_ENUM {
  FOO,
  BAR,
  BAZ // has a few different ones.
} LIB_B_ENUM
```

I would like to use both of them in `libb` like this:

```
int
some_function() {
  if (LIB_A_ENUM.FOO) {
    // ...
  } else if (LIB_B_ENUM.FOO) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Wondering how to do that sort of thing. I'm imagining I should just create a bunch of global variables like:

```
LIB_A_ENUM LIB_A_ENUM_FOO = FOO;
LIB_A_ENUM LIB_A_ENUM_BAR = BAR;
// ...
LIB_B_ENUM LIB_B_ENUM_FOO = FOO;
LIB_B_ENUM LIB_B_ENUM_BAR = BAR;
LIB_B_ENUM LIB_B_ENUM_BAZ = BAZ;
// ...

int
some_function() {
  if (LIB_A_ENUM_FOO) {
    // ...
  } else if (LIB_B_ENUM_FOO) {
    // ...
  }    
}
```

Wondering if that is the sort of approach to do it, or if there is a better way.

Actually, I realize you can't even have two different enums with the same keys. So perhaps the best thing is to just have the enum values be globally unique. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. Since the enum values are store in global scope, they have to be globally unique. The usual methods to prevent name collision in enum is to add the name enum's name as prefix for each of the enum values. It's kinda verbose but it should prevent errors in most cases.

```
typedef enum LIB_A_ENUM {
  LIB_A_ENUM_FOO,
  LIB_A_ENUM_BAR
} LIB_A_ENUM;

typedef enum LIB_B_ENUM {
  LIB_B_ENUM_FOO,
  LIB_B_ENUM_BAR,
  LIB_B_ENUM_BAZ
} LIB_B_ENUM;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The C language requires that the names of *enumeration constants* do not clash with each other and other identifiers *in the same scope*. Not even global variables are going to help because you cannot `#include` the 2 headers at the same time...

So your choices boil down to:

- change the enumeration constants so that they will have a prefix... (preferred!)

  - if you can't change the library headers, then perhaps you can `#define` a macro before inclusion of the clashing header, and `#undef` afterwards
- don't use them in the same translation unit
- or if you're really lucky, you can `#include` one of the headers *within a function*; the definition there wouldn't clash with the outer one.