# How to convert an ASCII character into an int in C

Tags: c, ascii, character

How can I convert an ASCII character into an int in C?

Comment: C does not have an "ascii character" datatype so this question is meaningless.

Comment: this is so ambiguos topic that means 1)'1' to 1 OR 2)'@' to 64; Im looking for the first one

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What about:

```
int a_as_int = (int)'a';
```

Comment: I'll add the necessary reference to the argument: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars

Answer (score 19):

I agree to Ashot and Cwan, but maybe you like to convert an ascii-cipher like '7' into an int like 7?

Then I recoomend:

```
char seven = '7';
int i = seven - '0';
```

<strike>or, maybe you get a warning,</strike>

```
int i = (int) (seven - '0');
```

corrected after comments, thanks.

Comment: There's no warning for that in C.

Comment: If there were a warning, you would be more likely to get it for the first line, which converts a larger type (`'7'` is an int) to a smaller type (char).

Answer (score 16):

Are you searching for this:

```
int c = some_ascii_character;
```

Or just converting without assignment:

```
(int)some_ascii_character;
```

Answer (score 12):

Use the **ASCII** to Integer `atoi()` function which accepts a string and converts it into an integer:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int num = atoi("23"); // 23
```

If the string contains a decimal, the number will be truncated:

```
int num = atoi("23.21"); // 23
```

Comment: "23" is not an ASCII character, so this has no bearing on the (unclear) question.

Answer (score 6):

A char value in C is implicitly convertible to an int. e.g, `char c; ... printf("%d", c)` prints the decimal ASCII value of `c`, and `int i = c;` puts the ASCII integer value of `c` in `i`. You can also explicitly convert it with `(int)c`. If you mean something else, such as how to convert an ASCII digit to an int, that would be `c - '0'`, which implicitly converts `c` to an int and then subtracts the ASCII value of `'0'`, namely 48 (in C, character constants such as `'0'` are of type int, not char, for historical reasons).

Answer (score 2):

You mean the ASCII ordinal value? Try type casting like this one:

```
int x = 'a';
```

Comment: @Jim Balter Sorry if it's obvious but I was wondering how this is c++ as opposed to c. Is it because of the terminology or am I missing something?

Comment: @quasiverse Look at the edit -- that is, click the "43 mins ago" link. Note that my comment was posted 48 minutes ago. Beware of this in general -- it will bite you at SO.

Comment: Oops, silly me, those are the times I saw when I posted that but of course those aren't the times that people will see when reading it.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else told you, you can convert it directly... UNLESS you meant something like "how can I convert an ASCII Extended character to its UTF-16 or UTF-32 value". This is a TOTALLY different question (one at least as good). And one quite difficult, if I remember correctly, if you are using only "pure" C. Then you could start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114611/what-is-the-best-unicode-library-for-c/114643#114643

(for ASCII Extended I mean one of the many "extensions" to the ASCII set. The 0-127 characters of the base ASCII set are directly convertible to Unicode, while the 128-255 are not.). For example ISO_8859-1 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1 is an 8 bit extensions to the 7 bit ASCII set, or the (quite famous) codepages 437 and 850.

Comment: ASCII (0-127) characters in any UTF format are identical to their integer representation.

Comment: @Chris But at least 50% of times, when someone speaks of ASCII he means "ASCII Extended"... But yes, it would be interesting to put this note in the reply. Thanks.

Comment: ASCII characters range in value from 0 to 127, so converting them to UTF-16 or UTF-32 is just a cast. Perhaps you mean something different, such as converting various byte encodings like UTF-8, ISO 8859-1 etc.

Comment: "ASCII extended" is a poor term that does not have a unique referent, or even close; there are numerous "extended" ASCII encodings, or "code pages" as some proprietary-minded commercial vendors call them.

Answer (score 0):

**It is not possible with the C99 standard library**, unless you manually write a map from character constants to the corresponding ASCII int value.

Character constants in C like `'a'` are not guaranteed to be ASCII.

C99 only makes some guarantees about those constants, e.g. that [digits be contiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35936519/895245).

The word ASCII only appears on the [C99 N1256 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) in footer notes, and footer note 173) says:

> In an implementation that uses the seven-bit US ASCII character set, the printing characters are those
>   whose values lie from 0x20 (space) through 0x7E (tilde); the control characters are those whose
>   values lie from 0 (NUL) through 0x1F (US), and the character 0x7F (DEL).

implying that ASCII is not the only possibility

Comment: None of this is relevant to the question (the meaning of which is unclear).

Comment: @JimBalter thanks for the feedback. Can you point out to the correct standard quote that says that `(int)'a' == 0x61` is not guaranteed, and explain what this my quote is referring to?