# Determine if char is a num or letter

Tags: c, char, alphanumeric

How do I determine if a `char` in C such as `a` or `9` is a number or a letter?

Is it better to use:

```
int a = Asc(theChar);
```

or this?

```
int a = (int)theChar
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You'll want to use the `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` standard functions in `<ctype.h>`.

```
char c = 'a'; // or whatever

if (isalpha(c)) {
    puts("it's a letter");
} else if (isdigit(c)) {
    puts("it's a digit");
} else {
    puts("something else?");
}
```

Answer (score 38):

chars are just integers, so you can actually do a straight comparison of your character against literals:

```
if( c >= '0' && c <= '9' ){
```

This applies to all characters.  [See your ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

[ctype.h](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.2.html) also provides functions to do this for you.

Comment: This is correct, but not because ASCII is guaranteed, but because of the contiguity of digits: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35936519/895245

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. And I think most of people do need this answer when resolving any kind of exercise at university

Answer (score 14):

`<ctype.h>` includes a range of functions for determining if a `char` represents a letter or a number, such as `isalpha`, `isdigit` and `isalnum`.

The reason why `int a = (int)theChar` won't do what you want is because `a` will simply hold the integer value that represents a specific character. For example the ASCII number for `'9'` is 57, and for `'a'` it's 97.

Also for ASCII:

- Numeric - `if (theChar >= '0' && theChar <= '9')`
- Alphabetic - 
   `if (theChar >= 'A' && theChar <= 'Z' || theChar >= 'a' && theChar <= 'z')`

Take a look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to see for yourself.

Comment: The check for '0' <= x <= '9' is correct for all standard-compliant implementations (ASCII or not is irreverent). C requires that decimal digits have a contiguous representation. As for letters, all bets are off.

Answer (score 12):

Neither of these does anything useful. Use `isalpha()` or `isdigit()` from the standard library. They're in `<ctype.h>`.

Answer (score 7):

If `(theChar >= '0' && theChar <='9')` it's a digit. You get the idea.

Answer (score 6):

You can normally check for ASCII letters or numbers using simple conditions

```
if ((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'))
{
    /*This is an alphabet*/
}
```

For digits you can use

```
if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
{
    /*It is a digit*/
}
```

But since characters in C are internally treated as [ASCII values](http://codeforwin.org/2015/05/ascii-codes.html) you can also use ASCII values to check the same.

[How to check if a character is number or letter](http://codeforwin.org/2015/05/c-program-to-check-alphabet-digit-special-character.html)

Comment: as every intermediate c text mentions, it is not guaranteed that c uses ascii so this wont work "everywhere"

Answer (score 3):

**C99 standard on `c >= '0' && c <= '9'`**

`c >= '0' && c <= '9'` (mentioned [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8611845/895245)) works because [C99 N1256 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 5.2.1 "Character sets" says:

> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the
>   value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.

ASCII is not guaranteed however.