# How get number between two words in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string pattern like following.

```
sales_order/view/order_id/155/key/0ee9098a18ccbca0879bfa93355fa1c7/
```

I want to get the number between "order_id" and "key"  text this number can be of any length.
How can I find the number between these two words?

This number '155' is dynamic.

Comment: if it iss fixed order then break by substring

Comment: [URL- find ascii](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611815/determine-if-char-is-a-num-or-letter) you could derive a code by checking for ascii and split the number from string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a regex:

```
var num = +( /order_id\/(\d+)\//.exec( str ) || '' )[ 1 ]
```

The `|| ''` piece of that is in case there is no match.  Also, if you specifically want to check for `key`, just add that to the end (between the two `//`'s at the end there)

Answer (score 2):

Try with **split** this

```
var url = "sales_order/view/order_id/155/key/0ee9098a18ccbca0879bfa93355fa1c7/"
var stuff = url.split('/');
var order_id = stuff['3'];    //since segment 4 will be the order id
alert("Order id is "+ order_id);
```

You can also get the individual url segments with this method....

Answer (score 1):

try http://jsfiddle.net/hSHkE/

```
 <div class="test">sales_order/view/order_id/155/key/0ee9098a18ccbca0879bfa93355fa1c7/</div>


var test=  $('.test').html().split('/')[3];
    alert(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
var str="sales_order/view/order_id/155/key/0ee9098a18ccbca0879bfa93355fa1c7/";
var n=str.indexOf("order_id/");
var m=str.indexOf("/key");

alert(str.substring(n + ("order_id/").length,m));
```

### [Live Demo: JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HrF6x/)