# How to write encryption function in C

Tags: c

Program take a text and n value. Add this n value each character. (Don’t add n numeric characters).

For exemple:

n=1

input:

```
akm101
```

output:

```
bln101
```

I have tried this but didn't execute.

```
while( letter != EOF ){
    fscanf(inp, "%c", &letter);
    if(47 < letter && letter < 58)
        printf("%c",letter);
    else 
        printf("%c", letter+n);
}
```

Comment: You must have mistaken SO for a site where other people do your homework.

Comment: cryptography is not a simple topic

Comment: So, what have you tried? And what is your question?

Comment: I add my tried function. Sorry.

Comment: @CyberTR post something that actually compiles. And explain what you're having trouble understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is probably homework, where the objective is learning rather than producing a correct answer, I'll offer some guidance.

- Loop through each character in the string.
- If the character [is a letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611815/determine-if-char-is-a-num-or-letter), increment the value of the character at that position by one
- Output the result of this loop.

http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Thanks but how i add increment value please look at my tried function. What is my mistake?

Comment: printing infinity space character

Comment: @CyberTR:  `letter` must be an `int`, not a `char`.