# C Programming : Outputting the result of a text based math problema?

Tags: c

For school, I'm currently learning C. Coming from Javascript, I'm trying to adapt to the way C is written. The syntax can be a bit confusing. I checked and there are a lot of obsolete functions my teacher used for examples.

My question is based on expression matching.

So let's assume I have a math question like this:

```
If Hanna has 100 apples and John 32 apples, then what is the sum?
```

How would I tell the program to interpret the sentence as `1+2` and then output the result?

In javascript, I usually use regular expressions but in C, this is really hard to accomplish or understand since regex is not a standard feature.

First: `printf(A operation B)`

I would need to iterate over each letter of the string and check if any of the letters include `0-9`. If match is found then the first number is stored in variable A and the second number in Variable B. If sum is found, then it stores + in the operation variable. As a consequence the variables within `printf` become assigned and I get the result.

Now how do I do this technically in C?

Comment: What kind of `obsolete` functions does your teacher use?

Comment: In C you are likely to use regex libraries rather than trying to roll your own, especially if you are a beginner in the language. Without using the full power of regular expressions, It wouldn't be hard to scan a string to extract numbers and check for key words such as `sum`, though that seems like a pretty fragile way to parse it. `strtok()` is the closest to a readily-available low-tech solution.

Comment: I think for him it's too early to use regex in C, learn the language before that

Comment: This looks like a job for `strtok` as @johnColeman pointed out.  I suspect that's the point of the assignment.  If it is, @asperger, you may be interested to know that this is not obsolete at all but sits at the heart of many if not all compilers written in (or produced by a compiler compiler) in C.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the following:
- Only one line has to be read.
- There are only two numbers in the line.
- The type of operation is indicated by a known set of words. For example, "sum", "multiplication" and so on.

The pseudocode is:

- Read the whole line and store it in a string (in C, a variable whose type is char *)
- Read first number, "A".
- Read first number, "B".
- Convert the strings into numbers. You can use the standard function "atoi".
- Do the operation (sum, multiplication, etc.)

For calculating the result, in C you have to use conditional blocks.
Something like that:

```
char * operator;

if (strcmp("sum", operator) == 0)
  result = A + B;
else if (strcmp("multiplication", operator) == 0)
  result = A * B;
..............
..............

printf("\nThe result is %d\n", sum);
```

Comment: To determine if the char is a number, read the answers to this SO question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611815/determine-if-char-is-a-num-or-letter

Comment: isnt atoi obsolete? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710018/why-shouldnt-i-use-atoi

Comment: My answer is above, because it didn't fit as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

NO, **atoi** is not obsolete.

However, **strtol** should be used if you are dealing with very big numbers, you are using a base other than 10 (non-decimal values) or you need to perform error-checking.

```
num = atoi(str);
```

is equivalent to

```
strtol(str, NULL, 10);
```

for most of the cases

Lundin, a very knowledgable C programmer, says in [atoi() — string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488569/atoi-string-to-int), that

"*atoi is not deprecated, your source is incorrect. Nothing in the current C standard ISO 9899:2011 indicates this (see for example chapter 6.11 future language directions), nor anything in earlier standards.*"

For the sake of completeness, I recommend you keep on reading his answer, although it's not the accepted answer, but I do think it's the most comprehensive one.

You will find the **atoi** function in many situations, but it's good to know about **strtol**, as well.