# How to accept character input only in C?

Tags: c, arrays

This program just count the the vowels in the word you type into the program. but I want this program accept only characters not a number. Is there a way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 50

int countVowel(char[]);

void main()
{
    char text[MAX];
    int cVowel, sum;
    printf("Enter text : ");
    scanf("%s", text);
    cVowel = countVowel(text);
    printf("Text : [%s] has %d vowels", text, cVowel);

}

int countVowel(char t[])
{
    int i = 0, count = 0;
    while (i < MAX && t[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (t[i] == 'A' || t[i] == 'a' || t[i] == 'E' || t[i] == 'e'
                || t[i] == 'I' || t[i] == 'i' || t[i] == 'O' || t[i] == 'o'
                || t[i] == 'u' || t[i] == 'U')

            count++;
        i++;

    }
    return (count);

}
```

I've tried using atoi but it didn't work :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if char is a num or letter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611815/determine-if-char-is-a-num-or-letter)

Comment: What do you mean by "accept"? Ignore any other character? Return an error when the input text contains anything but a character?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strpbrk](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strpbrk/):

> Returns a pointer to the first occurrence in str1 of any of the
>   characters that are part of str2, or a null pointer if there are no
>   matches.

```
int main(void) /* void main is not a valid signature */
{
    char text[MAX];
    int cVowel, sum;

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter text : ");
        scanf("%s", text);
        if (strpbrk(text, "0123456789") == NULL) {
            break;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Keine Lust's answer is correct if you want to disregard an *entire* string if it contains numeric characters.

If you just want to ignore them, then while iterating over your string, check if the current character is `>= 48` and `<= 57` (as per the [ASCII character table](http://www.asciitable.com/)]. If that condition is true, then simply `continue;` the iteration.