# Converting ASCII to int in Arduino

Tags: arduino, type-conversion, ascii

I am trying to get user input from the serial monitor to turn a stepper motor according to the input. However my code returns the ASCII value rather than the original input.

```
#include <Stepper.h>

Stepper small_stepper(steps_per_motor_revolution, 8, 10, 9, 11);

void setup() {
  // Put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Ready");
}


void loop() {

  // Put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int Steps2Take = Serial.read();
  Serial.println(Steps2Take); // Printing
  if (Steps2Take == -1)
    Steps2Take = 0;
  else {
    small_stepper.setSpeed(1000); // Setting speed
    if (Steps2Take > 0)
      small_stepper.step(Steps2Take * 32);
    else
      small_stepper.step(-Steps2Take * 32);
    delay(2);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ParseInt   blocks, which is just nice in your demo case, but will disturb in real scenarios...

Comment: Because you are new I want to remark that is is possible to accept,  if you like,  the answer. There is a little "tip" that will become green :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it is just a "type-conversion" problem, you can use something like this:

```
int a_as_int = (int)'a';
```

or

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int num = atoi("23"); //atoi = ascii to integer
```

as it was point out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322056/how-to-convert-an-ascii-character-into-an-int-in-c).

Does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the .toInt() function.

You should read the string from your serial and after that convert it to integer.

```
Serial.print(Serial.readString().toInt());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this three ways!  Notice, if the number is greater than 65535 then you have to use a long variable.  With decimals use float variable.

1. You can use the toInt(), or toFloat() which require a String type variable.  Heads up as the toFloat() is very time consuming.

   ```
      // CODE:
      String _int = "00254";
      String _float = "002.54"; 
      int value1 = _int.toInt();
      float value2 = _float.toFloat();
      Serial.println(value1);
      Serial.println(value2);

      // OUTPUT:
      254
      2.54
   ```
2. You could use the atoi.  The function accepts a character array and then converts it to an integer.

   ```
      // CODE:
      // For some reason you have to have +1 your final size; if you don't you will get zeros.
      char output[5] = {'1', '.', '2', '3'}; 
      int value1 = atoi(output);
      float value2 = atof(output);
      Serial.print(value1);
      Serial.print(value2);

      // OUTPUT:
      1
      1.23
   ```
3. If you had a Character Array and and wanted to convert it to a string because you didn't know the length...like a message buffer or something, I dunno.  You could use this below to change it to a string and then implement the toInt() or toFloat().

   ```
     // CODE:
     char _int[8];
     String data = "";
     for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
       data += (char)_int[i];
     }

     char buf[data.length()+1];
     data.toCharArray(buf, data.length()+1);
   ```