# Can an array in C be indexed by a character?

Tags: c, arrays

```
void shifttable(char p[]) {
    int i, j, m;
    m = strlen(p);
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        t[i] = m;
    for (j = 0; j < m - 1; j++)
        t[p[j]] = m - 1 - j;
}
```

I think, `t[p[j]]=m-1-j;` part, is indexed using a character.
Can someone explain me how its actually working?

Comment: Add an `(int)` and it would be clear, without changing the functionality of the code.

Comment: How is this code called?

Comment: [link](http://c-program-example.com/2011/10/c-program-to-search-the-perticulur-pattern-in-the-string-using-horspool-method.html)

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322056/how-to-convert-an-ascii-character-into-an-int-in-c). [Or this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c).

Comment: Why would you fill the entire t array with the string length if you just overwrite it all? Edit: Never mind...

Comment: im not overwriting all,just the ones in p

Comment: @user202729: How would casting to `(int)` be helpful?

Comment: @KeithThompson Probably easier to understand?

Comment: @user202729: Not really. The easiest way is to understand that `char` is an integer type, and therefore a valid array index.

Answer (score 1):

The array indexing operator is treated as `*(arr + index)`.

When one operand of the binary `+` operator is a pointer, the other operand must be an integral type.

`char` is an integral type.

Hence,

```
t[p[j]] = m-1-j;
```

is a legal statement.

Answer (score 0):

`p[j]` returns the ascii code of `j`-th character in `p[]`, which is used later as index in `t` (the ascii code is extended to int by the compiler, see *integer promotions*).

Answer (score 0):

The character will be converted to equivalent ascii value and it acts as an index to an array. Below piece of code gives you an example,

```
void main()
{
   int a[10];

   a['\t'] = 10;

   printf("%d\n",a[9]);
}
```

Output: 10

Here ascii value of tab is 9 so a[9] will be 10. Please refer https://www.asciitable.com/ for decimal and hex equivalent of character.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

`char` is an integral type. It can be used as an index value for the `[]` operator. Note however that `t['0']` is not the same element as `t[0]`. The value of `'0'` depends on the encoding used on the platform. Most environments use ASCII for the source and execution character sets, where `'0'` has the value 48.

Indexing through character values is useful for many algorithms, especially searching and word matching.  Typical implementations of the functions in `<ctype.h>` use arrays of 257 entries (or sometimes 384 entries for safety) where the function argument is used as an index.

> Yet there is a major problem in using `char` values an index variables: the `char` type can be **signed** or **unsigned** by default, so the range of its values can encompass negative values. In the code fragment, if `t` is an array or a pointer to the beginning of an array, any character in `p` with a negative value will cause an access outside the boundaries of the array, which has **undefined behavior**.
>
> It is advisable to raise the warning level so the compiler diagnoses such uses that are well hidden potential bugs. Use `gcc -Wall` or `clang -Weverything`.

To avoid this potential problem, the code should be modified this way:

```
#define MAX 256
int t[MAX];
void shifttable(char p[]) {
    int i, j, m;
    m = strlen(p);
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        t[i] = m;
    for (j = 0; j < m - 1; j++)
        t[(unsigned char)p[j]] = m - 1 - j;
}
```

Note also that `i`, `j`, `m` and the `t` array should have type `size_t` to handle strings longer than `INT_MAX`.