# get numbers value from a char array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have this char array:

```
char movimiento[]="L30 G10 L50 G-45 L-10 G50"
```

I want to get the value of the number after the letter `'L'` and store them into an integer variable to use it afterward

eg. `30, 50, -10`

I've tried this as ASCII code numbers start from 0==48 but I don't know how to store the chars into an integer: concat 3, 0 and store them into an integer.

```
int i = 0;
while(movimiento[i] != '\0'){
    if(movimiento[i]=='L'){
        while(movimiento[i]!=' '){
        printf("%d",(movimiento[i+1]-48));
        i++;
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine the size of my array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c)

Comment: This may be helpful: [How to convert a string to integer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/how-to-convert-a-string-to-integer-in-c)

Comment: You are close. After you find the L, call [strtol](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol)

Comment: @MFisherKDX I have trouble understanding how to implement the method

Comment: You should not use magic numbers like `48` if you can use `'0'` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an ascii character into an int in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322056/how-to-convert-an-ascii-character-into-an-int-in-c)

Hi, thats answer is what you need I guess - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5322080/4892907 
You can just cast char into int to get number from ASCII table, digits are 48 >= 57 (https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) so , like `char number1 = '1'` then ascii value `(int) number1` = 48

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You extract each integer following a "prefix" character, by first locating the prefix character using `strchr` and then calling `strtol` beginning with the next character *after* the prefix.

With your string, some prefix character taken from the command line (or using `'L'` by default if no argument is given) and a pointer to the beginning of your string:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char movimiento[]="L30 G10 L50 G-45 L-10 G50",  /* string */
        prefix = argc > 1 ? *argv[1] : 'L',         /* prefix (L default) */
        *p = movimiento;                            /* pointer to string */
```

You can then locate each occurrence of the prefix in your string with:

```
    while ((p = strchr (p, prefix))) {  /* while next prefix found */
        ...
```

Then it is just a matter of attempting the conversion to long beginning with the next character:

```
        errno = 0;          /* set errno zero */
        char *endptr;       /* end-pointer for strtol */
        long tmp = strtol (p + 1, &endptr, 0);  /* convert from next char */
```

and validating the return from `strtol` along with `endptr` to check for any error condition resulting from the conversion attempt:

```
        if (p == endptr)    /* no digits convertedd */
            p++;            /* advance to next and try again */
```

If digits were converted and `errno` remains unset and the value of the `long` returned by `strtol` is within the range of `int`, then you have a good integer value, use it any way you like:

```
        else {
            /* if no error and in range of int -- good value */
            if (!errno && INT_MIN <= tmp && tmp <= INT_MAX) {
                int val = (int)tmp;
                printf (n ? ", %d" : "%d", val);    /* output int */
                n++;        /* increment counter */
            }
            p = endptr;     /* advance to one-past last digit converted */
        }
```

(**note:** so long as there were digits converted, `p` is updated with `endptr` to point to the next character after the last digit converted, see [man 3 strtol](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html))

You are basically done. You can check whether at least one number was output and tidy up by outputting a newline in that case with:

```
    if (n) putchar ('\n');  /* if integers found tidy up with newline */
}
```

Putting it altogether, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char movimiento[]="L30 G10 L50 G-45 L-10 G50",  /* string */
        prefix = argc > 1 ? *argv[1] : 'L',         /* prefix (L default) */
        *p = movimiento;                            /* pointer to string */
    int n = 0;                                      /* counter */

    while ((p = strchr (p, prefix))) {  /* while next prefix found */
        errno = 0;          /* set errno zero */
        char *endptr;       /* end-pointer for strtol */
        long tmp = strtol (p + 1, &endptr, 0);  /* convert from next char */

        if (p == endptr)    /* no digits convertedd */
            p++;            /* advance to next and try again */
        else {
            /* if no error and in range of int -- good value */
            if (!errno && INT_MIN <= tmp && tmp <= INT_MAX) {
                int val = (int)tmp;
                printf (n ? ", %d" : "%d", val);    /* output int */
                n++;        /* increment counter */
            }
            p = endptr;     /* advance to one-past last digit converted */
        }
    }
    if (n) putchar ('\n');  /* if integers found tidy up with newline */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/intafterprefix
30, 50, -10
```

or, using the prefix `'G'`:

```
$ ./bin/intafterprefix G
10, -45, 50
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

---

**Handle Multiple Prefixes with `strpbrk`**

Also note if you wanted to be able to pass a string of prefixes allowing you to use `"G"` or `"L"` or `"GL"` as the prefix characters, you can make `prefix` a string and use `strpbrk` instead of `strchr`. For example using:

```
    char movimiento[]="L30 G10 L50 G-45 L-10 G50",  /* string */
        *prefix = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "L",         /* prefix (L default) */
    ...
    while ((p = strpbrk (p, prefix))) { /* while next prefix found */
       ...
```

**Example Use/Output**

That would then allow you to search for any or all prefixes, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/intafterprefix2
30, 50, -10

$ ./bin/intafterprefix2 G
10, -45, 50

$ ./bin/intafterprefix2 GL
30, 10, 50, -45, -10, 50
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <ctype.h>  // isalnum
#include <stdio.h>  // printf
#include <stdlib.h> // atoi
#include <string.h> // memset

int main() {
    char arr[256] = "L30 G10 L55434 G-45 L-10 G50 L3";
    char buf[256];
    memset(buf, 0, 256);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == 'L') {
            size_t count = 0;
            while (isalnum(arr[i]) || arr[i] == '-') {
                ++i;
                buf[count++] = arr[i];
            }
            int number = atoi(buf);
            printf("%d\n", number);
            memset(buf, 0, 256);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you could use sscanf

```
char movimiento[]="L30 G10 L50 G-45 L-10 G50";

struct coords { int l; int g; } coords[3];
if ( sscanf(movimiento, "L%d G%d L%d G%d L%d G%d"
  , &coords[0].l 
  , &coords[0].g
  , &coords[1].l 
  , &coords[1].g
  , &coords[2].l 
  , &coords[2].g
  ) == 6 )
{
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(coords)/sizeof(coords[0]); ++i)      
  {
    printf( "%d, %d\n", coords[i].l, coords[i].g );
  }
}
```