# why sizeof('a') is 4 in C?

Tags: c, char, sizeof, literals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are C character literals ints instead of chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char b = 'c';
    printf("here size is %zu\n",sizeof('a'));
    printf("here size is %zu",sizeof(b));
}
```

here output is (See live demo [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/i9eRmJ89zinRCNNg).)

```
here size is 4 
here size is 1
```

I am not getting why `sizeof('a')` is 4 ?

Comment: See [Why are C character literals ints instead of chars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because in C character constants, such as 'a' have the type `int`.

There's a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/charstring/sizeofchar.html) about this suject:

> Perhaps surprisingly, **character constants in C are of type int**, so
>   sizeof('a') is sizeof(int) (though this is another area where C++
>   differs).

Answer (score 10):

The following is the famous line from the famous `C` book - `The C programming Language` by `Kernighan & Ritchie` with respect to a character written between single quotes.

`A character written between single quotes represents an integer value equal to the numerical value of the character in the machine's character set.`

So `sizeof('a')` is equivalent to `sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 3):

'a' by default is an integer and because of that you get size of int in your machine 4 bytes.

char is 1 bytes and because of this you get 1 bytes.