# sizeof(c) and size('a') gives different result . ( c is character variable)

Tags: c, char, ascii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are C character literals ints instead of chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars)
>   [why sizeof('a') is 4 in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654837/why-sizeofa-is-4-in-c)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char ch;
  fflush(stdin);
  ch=getchar();
  printf("ch= %d a=%d char=%d", sizeof(ch),sizeof('a'),sizeof(char));
}
```

I type in 'a' (without quotes) as input , and the output I got in my ***gcc version 4.5.1*** is :

```
ch= 1 a=4 char=1
```

My question is :

If `sizeof(c)` is `1` , then how can `sizeof('a')` be `4` ?

Comment: This difference between C and C++ is really only marginal. In both languages expressions of type `char` are automatically promoted to `int` in most contexts. As a result in operations such as `'0' + 5` the computation is done with `int` anyhow.

Comment: @Jens: For once you're wrong. Promotions don't come into play at all with `sizeof`. It's purely a matter of the actual type of character literals, which **is** a big difference between C and C++.

Comment: @R.. this is basically what I meant, therefore I said "most". Perhaps I missed to  express my pov clearly. The only contexts where this distinction is relevant are `sizeof` and perhaps assignment. In all *other* contexts `char` promotes (basically) to `int`. Whether or not this is a big difference or not is really a question of appreciation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On most of the systems 'a'== 97, which ASCII value of the character 'a'.

for e.g:

```
int i = 97;
char c = i;
```

If you print the value of variable `c` with the option '%c' you'll see 'a' on the screen. for your question we can deduce  `sizeof('a')` as `sizeof(i)` equable to `sizeof(97)`;

You should be able to find this in C standards document.

Answer (score 10):

In C, a literal character (e.g., `'a'`), is an `int`, not a `char`.  In C++, however, literal characters are actual `char`s.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Could you point me to some compiler docs for these?

Comment: For C, the C99 standard 6.4.4.4/10 "Character constants" says, "An integer character constant has type `int`".  C++03 says in 2.13.2 "Character literals", "An ordinary character literal that contains a single c-char has type
`char`".

Comment: Wow, that's useful @MichaelBurr!

Comment: Also, for historic interest, Stroustrup says in "Design and Evolution of C++" that, "In C, the type of a character literal such as `'a'` is `int`. Surprisingly, giving `'a'` type `char` in C++ doesn't cause compatibility problems. Except for the pathological example `sizeof('a')`, every construct that can be expressed in both C and C++ gives the same result".

Answer (score 2):

Because in C character constants, such as 'a' have the type `int`.

There's a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/charstring/sizeofchar.html) about this suject:

> Perhaps surprisingly, **character constants in C are of type int**, so
>   sizeof('a') is sizeof(int) (though this is another area where C++
>   differs).

Comment: how C++ differs in this area ?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars