# Why sizeof('c') is returning 4 instead of 1?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are C character literals ints instead of chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars)

http://ideone.com/lHYY8

```
int main(void)
{
        printf("%d %d\n", sizeof('c'), sizeof(char));
        return 0;
}
```

Why does `sizeof('c')` return 4 instead of 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One (possibly even more extreme) oddity that also somehow justifies this, is the fact that character literals are *not* limited to being single character.

Try this:

```
printf("%d\n", 'xy');
```

This is sometimes useful when dealing with e.g. binary file formats that use 32-bit "chunk" identifiers, such as [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#.22Chunks.22_within_the_file). You can do things like this:

```
const int chunk = read_chunk_from_file(...);
if(chunk == 'IHDR')
  process_image_header(...);
```

There might be portability issues with code like this though, of course the above snippet assumes that `read_chunk_from_file()` magically does the right thing to transform the big-endian 32-bit value found in the PNG file into something that matches the value of the corresponding multi-character character literal.

Comment: +1 Will `'IHDR'` equal the same thing on all platforms ?

Comment: @cnicutar: Per the C standard, no, it's entirely implementation-defined. gcc makes it the same on all, though. (The same **value**, not the same representation...)

Comment: @cnicutar: I don't think so, no ... That's why I wrote the part about `read_chunk_from_file()` needing to be smart in order to support this usage.

Comment: @unwind if 'x' gives the ascii code what does 'xy' give?

Answer (score 16):

Because in C character constants have the type `int`, not `char`. So `sizeof('c') == sizeof(int)`. Refer to this [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/charstring/sizeofchar.html)

> Perhaps surprisingly, **character constants in C are of type int**, so
>   sizeof('a') is sizeof(int) (though this is another area where C++
>   differs).

Comment: Wow, you learn something new every day. Gotta love C's insane little oddities like this.

Answer (score 2):

The following is the famous line from the famous `C` book - `The C programming Language` by `Kernighan & Ritchie` with respect to a character written between single quotes.

> A character written between single quotes represents an integer value equal to the numerical value of the character in the machine's character set.

So `sizeof('a')` is equivalent to `sizeof(int)`

And this question is a duplicate of [why sizeof('a') is 4 in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654837/why-sizeofa-is-4-in-c)

Comment: This K&R sentence has nothing to do with the fact that a character constant is of type `int` in C. `char`, `short` or even `_Bool` are also integers.

Comment: @ouah Could you please elaborate your first statement? w.r.t second statement, you can add `enum` to the list!

Answer (score 1):

cnicutar is completely right of course. I just wanted to add the reason for this. If you look at functions line `fgetc`, you'll notice that it also returns an int. It's because a char can represent any character from `0x00` to `0xFF`, but an additional value is needed in order to represent EOF. So functions that return a character from input or a file often return an int, which can be compared with EOF, which is usually defined to be `-1`, but it can be anything that isn't a valid character.

Comment: Actually `EOF` is required to be negative and thus disjoint from any possible value of *unsigned* char converted to `int` unless the width of `int` is the same as `CHAR_BIT`.