# How come I can compare a char with an int?

Tags: c, type-promotion

I am not very familiar with C so I am a bit confused on the type safety of the language.

For example.

```
char* my_pointer;

my_pointer = malloc(sizeof(char));

if (*my_pointer == 0b0000)
{
    // this might be true or false, doesn't matter
}
```

How come the code runs? Why doesn't it just blow up at `*my_pointer == 0b0000`?

Shouldn't `*my_pointer` return a char?

So technically shouldn't only something like `*my_pointer == 'a'` be able to work?

Comment: when you dereference my_pointer you get a char, but then it's promoted to int same goes with the other value

Comment: @martin Woah, I think you might be on to something. Unfortunately as I am a total rookie at C, perhaps a more in depth explanation of what you mentioned would be an answer I would happily accept.

Comment: Standard C rules do not apply here as binary integer constants `0b0000` are not part of the language.

Comment: SO cannot replace a beginner's course. You should grab a C text book and learn about basic types and conversion rules.

Comment: [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)

Comment: Interestingly, `'a'` is also an `int`. [Why sizeof('a') is 4 in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654837/why-sizeofa-is-4-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C language does not have a dedicated "character" type with some isolated "character-only" semantics. `char` is just another integer type in C, just like, `short` or `int`. It just happens to be the smallest integer type. You can use `char` for integer arithmetic computations in the very same way you'd use any other integer type (albeit using `char` in that role is not a very good idea).

When you are comparing `char` and `int` you are simply comparing two integer values. Nothing unusual about it.

The rules of integer promotion say that `char` gets implicitly converted to `int` (provided the range fits) and then two `int` values are compared.

Your `*my_pointer == 'a'` example is actually no different from your original one. In C `'a'` is a character constant which represents an integer value of type `int`. I.e. there's no need to even promote `'a'` to `int` since it is already an `int`.

Comment: Does integer promotion happen for all in-built variable types in C?

Comment: @AlanSTACK: Integer promotion happens to small integer types `[signed/unsigned] char` and `[signed/unsigned] short`  in those contexts where the language specification says it should happen. Operator `==` happens to be one of such contexts.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `0b` is not a valid standard C prefix for integer constants. So you need to make sure you are following the specifics for the platform you are using.

That being said, as per the rules for  Equality operators (`==`), arithmetic conversion (integer promotion) rules are applicable for the operands, if both of them are of arithmetic type.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.9,

> If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are
>   performed. [...]

Answer (score 0):

You are simply comparing 2 integer values.This happens becouse `0b0000` is an integer literal and the value you get after dereferencing `my_pointer` is being promoted to int.

> If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int