# size of char type in C

Tags: c, char, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are C character literals ints instead of chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars)

folks,

I tried to print out the size of char in C. With the following code, I got the result output as

```
int, 4
char, 1
char?, 4
```

Why is the last one not the same as the 2nd one? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int a = 2;
    char b = '2';
    printf("int, %d\n",sizeof(a));
    printf("char, %d\n",sizeof(b));
    printf("char?, %d\n",sizeof('a'));
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars. In light of this, I'm voting to close (though it's not a bad question)

Comment: Discussion on this topic has been raised before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars

Comment: Note that `sizeof(char)` is 1, by definition --- `sizeof()` returns values in char units. Which aren't the same as bytes! AFAICT there is no way to get the size of a structure in _bytes_ without platform knowledge (i.e., how many bytes there are in a char).

Comment: @DavidGiven The C standard defines a “byte” as an “addressable unit of data storage large enough to hold any member of the basic character set of the execution environment”.  It also says, “The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand,” and “When applied to an operand that has type `char`... the result is 1.”  It also specifies the `CHAR_BIT` macro as the “number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte)”, in case you want to convert from native bytes to octets.

Comment: Yep. The C standard defines 'byte' to be equivalent to char. Which is _not the same_ as the machine's definition of byte. It's a huge, huge gotcha if ever you're dealing with exotic platforms where chars occupy more than one machine byte. Luckily, these are incredibly rare these days, so people rarely come across this, but when I first came across this in the spec I damn near threw my copy of K&R at the wall.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In C, a character constant like `'a'` has type `int`.

This is different from C++ and Java, where a character constant like `'a'` has type `char`,