# Pointer initializations

Tags: c

`char *p = "a";` is valid but not `int *p = 2;` and `char *p = 'a';` Why are they designed like that?

Comment: What's the necessity of `while` and `do...while`? Shouldn't `for` be enough? Technically yes, but having all three gives options to express yourself more clearly.

Comment: 1) "a" has some constant address in memory but 2 not.
2)To increase something **before** or **after**.

Comment: "a" is a `char[]` which can be converted to `char *`.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, beofre or after what? ;)

Comment: `char *` wants to be assigned a pointer to a character, `'a'` is just a character so you can't assign that. `"a"` is a pointer to a character, so that's OK to assign. `int *` wants a pointer to an integer, `2` is just an integer, not a pointer.

Comment: @StoryTeller errr. things going on, compiled things, assembly lines, branching.

Comment: It is perfectly clear what is asked in both cases. That is no reason to close this post. Vote to reopen.

Comment: Let's remove the second question and just deal with the first, which is legitimate, clear, and answerable.

Comment: for(int i=0;(i++)<20;){} how does this work for example?

Comment: @ChrisStratton The second question is perfectly fine. And the answer is: because the C language isn't sane and logical. Though since they are not related, they should have been posted as 2 different questions

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, the real need is syntactic sugar. Both operators return the variables value. But one returns the old value, and the second returns the new value.

Comment: The ++ operators should never be used together with most other operators anyhow, since it easily leads to poorly-defined behavior or unreadable code. And combining any ++ with other operators will yield no better machine code, just more unreadable C code.

Comment: @Lundin, IDK. Some idioms involving the increment operators are pretty self explanatory to any moderately experienced programmer. Consider `while(*p++)` for instance.

Comment: The *original* rationale for having both pre- and post-increment and decrement probably had something to do with the [PDP-11/20's set of addressing modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11_architecture#General_register_addressing_modes).  Note in particular that it has predecrement and postincrement, but not the other two.

Comment: I am adding second as a separate question.

Comment: @StoryTeller The problem is that it is not intuitive to anyone else. Experienced C programmers know all the pitfalls of the language. Given enough time, any weird crap will seem natural. Also, having double sets of ++ operators is completely superfluous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything wrritten inside `" "` is considered as string in C.So

`char *p = " a"` says you are passing base address of string to char pointer.which is Valid.

`int *p` says `p` is a pointer to integer so `p` can hold a address to integer so `int *p = 2` is not valid.

Similarly `char *p` is pointer to character so `p` can hold address of a character so `char *p = 'a'` is not valid because `'a'` is just a character not address to character.

Answer (score 3):

A typeof string literal is of `char[n]` and assignment to `char*` is fine.
Point is both are pointers.

`char *p = "a";` means `p` points to string `"a"` (some where in memory, type of `"a"` is `char[2]`).

```
   p            23   24
  +----+      +----+----+
  | 23 |      | a  | \0 |        
  +----+      +----+----+
```

Whereas `2` and `'a'` are of int type values, *not a valid address* hence following declarations are errors/warnings: *`"initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast"`*

```
int *p = 2; and   
char *p = 'a';
```

**note**: in [c](/questions/tagged/c) a char constant is int type, but *not* char [refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars).

Comment: Actually a string literal has type `char*`, for historical reasons, even though you shouldn't try to modify its contents.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a string literal is an array, not a pointer.  It does (like other arrays) decay into a pointer to its first element in most contexts.

Comment: @CarlNorum you means `char[]` not `const char*` ?

Comment: Strictly speaking in C the type of string literal is `char [N]`. It is an array, not a pointer, but there's no `const` in the type.

Comment: @Grijesh with gcc you can force the compiler to treat string litterals as 'const char *'. The option -Wwrite-strings will do that. While it is not standard C, it is really useful to make the code more robust.

Comment: @tristopia  I was unaware of this thanks tristopia, I just posted an answer because no one else was interested But I learnt. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Because `"a"` has a type of `char *`, and `2` doesn't have a type of `int *`. Note that `char *p = 'a'` is also invalid.