# literal character in C: is it an int or a char?

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion

If I declare this:

```
int i = 0 + 'A';
```

is `'A'` considered `char` or `int`?

some people might use:

```
int i = 0 + (int)'A';
```

but is this really necessary?

Comment: The latter is not needed. character literals are of type `int`.

Comment: Even if `'A'` was of type `char`, the cast would have no effect on all but the most exotic platforms. To be precise, if `'A'` was a signed char type (either `signed char` or `char` when it is signed), there could never be any difference, and if `A` was an unsigned `char` type (either `unsigned char` or `char` when it is unsigned), then `int` and `char` would have to be the same size for a difference to be visible.

Comment: What is the `0 + ` good for? Even in `0 + 'A'` it serves no purpose and even less :) in `0 + (int)'A'`.

Comment: `'A'` is a `char`, and `char` is a numeric type.  It will be implicitly cast to `int` when paired with `int` on a binary operator, per standard C casting rules.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/433895/62576

Comment: @HotLicks `'A'` is an `int`. C99 6.4.4.4:10 “An integer character constant has type int.”

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are C character literals ints instead of chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C, character constants such as `'A'` are of type `int`. In C++, they're of type `char`.

In C, the type of a character constant rarely matters. It's guaranteed to be `int`, but if the language were changed to make it `char`, most existing code would continue to work properly. (Code that explicitly refers to `sizeof 'A'` would change behavior, but there's not much point in writing that unless you're trying to distinguish between C and C++, and there are better and more reliable ways to do that. There are cases involving macros where `sizeof 'A'` might be sensible; I won't get into details here.)

In your code sample:

```
int i = 0 + 'A';
```

`0` is of type `int`, and the two operands of `+` are promoted, if necessary, to a common type, so the behavior is exactly the same either way. Even this:

```
char A = 'A';
int i = 0 + A;
```

does the same thing, with `A` (which *is* of type `char`) being promoted to `int`. Expressions of type `char` are usually, but not always, implicitly promoted to `int`.

In C++, character constants are of type `char` -- but the same promotion rules apply. When Stroustrup designed C++, he changed the type of character constants for consistency (it's admittedly a bit surprising that `A` is of type `int`), and to enable more consistent overloading (which C doesn't support). For example, if C++ character constants were of type `int`, then this:

```
std::cout << 'A';
```

would print `65`, the ASCII value of `'A'` (unless the system uses EBCDIC); it makes more sense for it to print `A`.

```
int i = 0 + (int)'A';
```

The cast is unnecessary in both C and C++. In C, `'A'` is already of type `int`, so the conversion has no effect. In C++, it's of type `char`, but without the cast it would be implicitly converted to `int` anyway.

In both C and C++, casts should be viewed with suspicion. Both languages provide implicit conversions in many contexts, and those conversions *usually* do the right thing. An explicit cast either overrides the implicit conversion or creates a conversion that would not otherwise take place. In many (but by no means all) cases, a cast indicates a problem that's better solved either by using a language-provided implicit conversion, or by changing a declaration so the thing being converted is of the right type in the first place.

(As Pascal Cuoq reminds me in comments, if plain `char` is unsigned *and* as wide as `int`, then an expression of type `char` will be promoted to `unsigned int`, not to `int`. This can happen only if `CHAR_BIT >= 16`, i.e., if the implementation has 16-bit or bigger bytes, *and* if `sizeof (int) == 1`, *and* if plain `char` is unsigned. I'm not sure that any such implementations actually exist, though I understand that C compilers for some [DSPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processor) do have `CHAR_BIT > 8`.)

Comment: What are your references? So accurate and beautiful answer!  Are you teacher?

Comment: “In C++, it's of type char, but without the cast it would be implicitly converted to int” You know what I am going to say, don't you? Alright, I won't say it.

Comment: The MISRA C committee put their collective feet down rather had on __no implicit conversions__ and many industries now use MISRA C for quality checking.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Who is talking about a conversion here? `'A'` has type `int`. `0` has type `int`. In C++, where `'A'` has type `char`, its becoming of type `int` is a *promotion* and it is unavoidable. If you write `(int)'A'` then `'A'` is promoted to `int` before the cast. See 6.3.1.1 in the C99 standard, for instance.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Your first comment: No, I don't. Your second comment: Unlike the `+` operator, a cast operator doesn't promote its argument; in C++, `(int)'A'` *does* convert the operand from `char` to `int`. (In many, but not all, contexts; the conversion would have occurred anyway; in `char c = 'A';`, there's no promotion.)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: No, just someone who's spent way too much time reading language standards and hanging out on Usenet.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: Avoiding implicit conversions in C or C++ would be very difficult (unless there's a compiler option to enforce it). Even `char c = 'A'` would violate the rule.

Comment: The first comment was, in reaction to “without the cast it would be implicitly converted to int”, that if `char` is unsigned and as wide as `int` (both of which appear from quick Google searches to be possible in C++), without the cast, `'A'` would not be promoted to `int` but to `unsigned int`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Ah, good point; I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Regarding the second comment, I do not see the sentence “The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may be used” (c99 6.3.1.1:2) as having any limitation on the context. In `char c; (short)c;` `c` is promoted to `int` before being cast to `short`, not that it makes any observable difference, but it makes coding rules that pretend to banish promotions in C look quite silly.

Comment: You need to read the beginning of 6.3, as well as the footnote. The sentence you quoted applies only to contexts where *integer promotion* occurs. The operand of a cast is not one of those contexts. Similarly, in an assignment: `char x = ..., y = ...; x = y;`, the value of `y` is not promoted to `int` and then converted back to `char`; it's just assigned as a `char`. The point is that C doesn't require support for *arithmetic* operations on types narrower than `int`; other operations are required.

Answer (score 10):

In C, `'A'` type is `int` (not char). I think some people do `int i = 0 + (int)'A';` in C++ (or make code useful in both C++/C).

Comment: In C++ `'A'` is `char` (not `int`): **Try** `sizeof('A'), sizeof(int), sizeof(char)` in C++ and in C both.

Comment: @carlos Someone might doing this because they don't know `'A'` is int in C. quit possible (casting is superflus because of implicit cast even in C++ also)

Comment: @carlos for [C code](http://ideone.com/x5RofP) and for [C++ code](http://ideone.com/J5b3TG)

Answer (score 0):

According to the standard ISO C99, the type of a literal character in C is `int`.

However, the literal characters, like 'c', have a range that fits in a `char`.
Thus, you can assign a literal character to a `char` variable without loss of information.

```
 char c = 'c'; /* 'c' is int, but (c == 'c') is true */
```

Comment: You are confusing the question here with the other question “Why do some standard library functions return an `int` in C?”. These two questions are completely different. The answer to the question “Why do some standard library functions return an `int` in C?” involves the type `unsigned char`. Your answer does not make sense for either question.

Comment: I dropped the EOF paragraph. I think the rest is fine.