# Type of character constant

Tags: c, types, character, constants

I am studying physics and in the lecture notes of our programming course it is written that a character constant, in C has type **char**, where by character constant I mean an expression like **'x'**.
After asking my lecturer if that was a mistake he said no. After showing him the C90, C99 and C11, where it is clearly written that a character constant has type **int** he still didn't say it was a mistake.

So before asking him again I wanted to assure myself that I got it the right way, and why it is that way, because it seems like a waste of memory.
Everything I found out about why it is that way, is that it is because of historic reasons, which is rather vague.
Also I would like to know why in C++ , they changed the type of a character constant to **char**.

EDIT: thanks a lot for the answers.

Comment: Look at this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars

Comment: The linked question answers the why for C and C++. And the C standard answers the "technical" part - yes,  `'x'` is of type `int` in C, `char` in C++.

Comment: `x` is (also) a character literal, which might help to overcome an assumed contradiction inducted by ambiguousness in the wording.

Comment: How does he justify his assertion that he's right and all three editions of the ISO C standard are wrong?

Comment: @KeithThompson: Compliance with the standard is voluntary; the standards agencies have no legal, ethical, or professional jurisdiction over the lecturer, nor do they have a trademark or other proprietary interest in the name “C”. :-)

Comment: @KeithThompson: I really don't know. I've asked him that myself without getting any answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Compliance with the standard may be voluntary, but since it's an introduction course, I think it really makes no sense to define things otherwise, especially when working with gcc during course which works with the standards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Online C language standard, 2011 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **6.4.4.4 Character constants**
> ...
> 2 An integer character constant is a sequence of one or more multibyte characters enclosed
> in single-quotes, as in `'x'`. A wide character constant is the same, except preﬁxed by the
> letter `L`, `u`, or `U`. With a few exceptions detailed later, the elements of the sequence are
> any members of the source character set; they are mapped in an implementation-deﬁned
> manner to members of the execution character set.
> ...
> 10 An integer character constant has type `int`. The value of an integer character constant
> containing a single character that maps to a single-byte execution character is the
> numerical value of the representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer.
> The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g.,
> `'ab'`), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte
> execution character, is implementation-deﬁned. If an integer character constant contains
> a single character or escape sequence, its value is the one that results when an object with
> type `char` whose value is that of the single character or escape sequence is converted to
> type `int`.

So yes, in C, single character constants such as `'x'` have type `int`.

<strike>*Why* this is the case is, AFAIK, largely lost to history<sup>1</sup>, although I suspect it was to minimize conversions when comparing against the results of `getchar` (which returns an `int`) or working with variadic functions like `printf` (which would automatically promote any expressions of type `char` to `int`).</strike>

Since C++ provided alternate mechanisms for I/O and type-generic operations, it made sense for character constants to have type `char`.

Does this matter *in practice*?  Not in my experience, but my experience in text processing isn't that extensive.

I should actually read what I copy from the standard; the reason is given in that snippet.  You can have multi-character constants like `'abc'`, which would not logically map to a single `char` value.

---

<strike><sup>1.  Now watch sometbody find an extensive quote from Ritchie or Kernighan explaining exactly why they did it</sup></strike>

Comment: What would be teh use for those mult-char constants though?

Answer (score 1):

You may find this code elucidating:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("size of char is %ld\n", sizeof(char));
    printf("size of const char is %ld\n", sizeof(const char));
    printf("size of int is %ld\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("size of 'x' is %ld\n", sizeof('x'));
}
```

Please compile on your system.  On my system (OS X, compiling with either `gcc -m32` or `gcc -m64`), the output is:

```
size of char is 1
size of const char is 1
size of int is 4
size of 'x' is 4
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from experience, when C was young, it was simpler for expressions to work mostly in `int`. The early compilers were much less complicated than today’s compilers. Additionally, programming languages generally were not as strongly typed as they are today.

It is not a waste of memory for character constants to have type `int`, because the C standard does not specify how they have to be kept in memory. Only objects, such as one declared with `int d;` must be assigned memory (and even then often only in the abstract computation model of C, not necessarily in the real computer). A C implementation may introduce the value of a character constant to the instructions that execute the program in any way it pleases, as long as the result is correct. E.g., it can store the value in a few bits of an immediate field in an instruction, without using all the space an`int` requires.

I expect C++ changed the type of character constants to `char` because it is moving toward stronger typing, with the aim of reducing human errors.