# C - Multiply char by int

Tags: c, string, int

Before I ask my question let me just say that I am a newbie to C, and do not know how to do a lot in it.

Anyway, the problem is that I need to print a specific number of characters. I first used Python, because that was a language that I was familiar with, and wrote this very simple program.

```
x = 5    
print('#' * x)
```

This is what I want to achieve, but in C. Sorry if this is a duplicate or a stupid question, but I have been puzzled and without answers, even after looking on the internet.

Comment: Sorry, C is a low-level system language. It doesn't really even have "strings" as a data type. You have to do all that yourself: allocate a character array, copy characters into it with a loop, even add the null terminator at the end. No shortcuts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for ( size_t ii = 0; ii < 5; ++ii )
    putchar('#');
```

Comment: Never knew of the putchar function before now, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use a loop to print it multiple times.

In C, a symbol between `''` has a type `char`, a character, *not* a string.  `char` is a numeric type, same as `int` but shorter.  It holds a numerical representation of the symbol (ASCII code).  Multiplying it with an integer gives you an integer.

A string, contained between `""` is an array of characters.  The variable will store a *pointer* to the first character.

Comment: In C character constants are of type `int`. You probably confusing with C++.

Comment: Well, I may have oversimplified.  But an explanation of what is an implementation-defined behavior and how it is supposed to work for 'ab' or for multibyte characters does not belong to this question.
For curious, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764538/type-of-character-constant

Comment: @ftynse: Type of character constants is not implementation-defined. It is *always* `int` (C99, `6.4.4.4p10`); for wide constants, it is `wchar_t` (`p11`).

Comment: @ftynse The `sizeof('a') == sizeof(int)` - this is not a implementation-defined behavior issue.  "An integer character constant has type `int`."

Comment: Even though I chose another answer to my question, I did like your explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use printf function. It allows you to format your output in the way you like. The way to get result you required is a for loop.

```
int i, x = 5;
for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    printf("#");
```

Comment: Using `printf` to in a loop to print individual characters is overkill; here `putchar` would suffice.