# Why char cannot be used

Tags: c

I'm new to C. From the book there is a sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int c;
  c = getchar();

  while (c != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
    c = getchar();
  }
}
```

The author writes a sentence like this:

> We can't use char since c must be big enough to hold EOF in addition to any possible char. Therefore we use int.

Trying to understand, I modified the code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  char c=getchar();

  while (c != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
    c = getchar();
  }

  if (c == EOF) {
    putchar('*');
  }
}
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, `*` was printed, which means `c` holds `EOF`, which confuses me. Can anybody explain a little bit about this?

Comment: Try indenting your code correctly

Comment: @Zhenxiao Hao Read the answer to this post : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/197625/storing-the-eof-end-of-file-character-in-a-char-type

Comment: The signature of `getchar` is `int getchar(void)`. It is a good practice to store return values of functions in variables or the same type as the return value. If a function returns an `int`, store its result in an `int`. The particular reason why this couldn't have been a char is provided by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21289924/96780).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `EOF` is a special sentinel value (implementation defined, but usually -1 as an `int` type), it can't be distinguished from the value 255 if stored in a `char` variable.  You need a type larger than 8 bits in order to represent all possibly byte values returned by `getchar()`, plus the special sentinel value `EOF`.  There are 257 different possible return values from `getchar()`.

Also, on a related note, [character literals in C like `'a'` have the type `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars).  In C++, on the other hand, character literals have the type `char`.  So you will see characters usually passed to and returned from C Standard Library functions as `int` types.

Answer (score 3):

When you press CTRL-D, `getchar()` returns a value that doesn't fit in `char`. So `char` takes as much of it as it can. Let's assume a common number for `EOF`: `0xFFFFFFFF`, in other words, -1. When this value is assigned to `char` (assuming it's signed), it will get a truncated value out of it, `0xFF`, which is also -1.

So your `if` becomes:

```
if ((char)-1 == (int)-1)
```

the `(char)-1` gets promoted to `int` to be able to compare it with `(int)-1`. Since on promotion of signed values, they get sign extended (to keep the original signed value), you end up comparing `-1` and `-1` which is true.

That said, this is only lucky. If you actually read a character with value `0xFF`, you would mistake it with `EOF`. Not to mention `EOF` may not be -1 in the first place. All of this aside, you shouldn't let your program truncate a value when assigning to a variable (unless you know what you are doing).

Answer (score 1):

`char` is, at least on your system, signed. Therefore, it can hold values from `-128` to `127`.

`EOF` is `-1` and is, therefore, one of them.

You code works, as the `-1` is retained. But as soon as you input the character which is equivalent to `255`, you get erroneously `-1` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The result of your `getchar()` is being stored as a`char` after performing a conversion *by-value*. The value in this case, is EOF likely (-1).

> **6.3.1.3-p1 Signed and unsigned integers**
>
> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type
>   other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it
>   is unchanged.

This is also accounted for during value comparison in your while-condition through value comparison via conversion:

> **6.5.9-p4 Equality Operators**
>
> If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed. Values of complex types are equal if and
>   only if both their real parts are equal and also their imaginary parts
>   are equal. Any two values of arithmetic types from different type
>   domains are equal if and only if the results of their conversions to
>   the (complex) result type determined by the usual arithmetic
>   conversions are equal.

Both `char` and `int` are integer types. Both can hold the integer-value (-1) on your platform. Therefore your code "works".

Answer (score 1):

The type char is an unsigned 8-bit value (actually I think it can be 7 bits for the standard ASCII table, but I have never seen it implemented like that).

EOF is implementation defined, but often -1.  That is a signed number (0xFFFFFFFF in a 32 bit machine).  Most compilers will probably truncate that to 0xFF to compare to a char, but that's also a valid (but rarely used) character, so you can't really be sure if you have hex value 255 or EOF (-1).

In addition, some code may be written to look for a return value of <0 to stop reading.  Obviously a char will never be less than zero.