# Macro alternative to _T("char") or _TEXT("char")

Tags: c, winapi, tchar

I know that the _T(x) macro converts a string literal to a unicode/multibyte
string based on a define, however I find it very annoying that I must make a 
underscore and the parenthesis, it really confuses me, I'm not quiet fluent with
macros so I don't know, is there a way to detect all string literals and convert
them to a proper unicode/multibyte string?

Comment: Unicode? Multi-byte? Drop C and go Python :)

Comment: Just don't bother, [a char literal is an *int*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars).  So it just doesn't matter.

Comment: Use `L` for your literals since I cannot believe you are building for Win98

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to avoid the macro completely if you want your code to be portable on Windows.  You can of course define your own macro like `#define t(x) whatever_T_does` if you want to save yourself some keystrokes, but this will probably anger future maintainers of your code.

Answer (score 1):

`_T()` and `_TEXT()` are C runtime macros, not Win32 macros.  `TEXT()` (no underscore) is the Win32 macro.  Even though they essentially do the same thing, you should use C runtime macros only with C functions, and Win32 macros with Win32 functions.  Don't mix them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the ability to compile for both multibyte and Unicode? You don't need any macro if you want multibyte. In a Unicode app it is easier to use L"literal string", which does not need the underscore or the parentheses.