# If character constants are of type `int', why are they assigned to variables of type `char`?

Tags: c, types

The C11 standard says that character constants (e.g., `'x'`) are of type `int`, not `char`. This surprised and confused me (especially as a relative beginner). I came across this answer [Why are C character literals ints instead of chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars), which somewhat cleared things up, but still left me wondering why it seems to be routine practice (at least in all the books and tutorials I've come across) to assign character constants to variables that are declared to be of type `char`. For example, why do we do

```
char initial = 's';
```

and not

```
int initial = 's';
```

And then, what happens when a constant of type `int` is assigned to a variable of type `char`? Is it switched into type `char`?

Answer (score 4):

The fact that character literals are of type `int` is only a half of the story. The other half is that their value is in the range of `char`. This is critical, because if you assign

```
char a = 65;
```

you get no warning, but if you do

```
char b = 56789;
```

you get a warning.

> why do we do `char initial = 's'` and not `int initial = 's'`?

This lets you avoid casting when assigning the variable to another variable of type `char`, or to an element of a `char[]` array:

```
char str[2];
str[0] = initial; // no cast when "initial" is of type "char"
```

There is one situation when you need to use `int` for variables storing `char` - when you use a `getc` / `fgetc` functionality, the result must be an `int`, not a `char`, in order to allow comparison with `EOF`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider `float x = 3.0;`  That sets a `double` `3.0` to a `float`.  Code could have been `float x = 3.0f;`.  The end result is the same.

Same with `char ch = 5;`. vs  `char ch = (char)5;`  In both case, `ch` gets the same value.

In the end, consider C was originally focused on types `int`, and `double` - that's it.  Types like `float`, `short`, `char`, `long` ,... are just deviations from the truly core types of C.  (Even `unsigned`, `bool` were afterthoughts.)

---

> what happens when a constant of type int is assigned to a variable of type char? Is it switched into type char?

The constant remains the type it was.  Assigning a constant of type `int` to a `char` does not change the type of the constant.  What can change is the value from the `int` when the original `int` value is outside the range of `char` and then saved in a `char`.

Answer (score 1):

If an `int` value is assigned to `char` variable, the value is converted to type `char`.

There are a few reasons for declaring a variable `char` rather than `int`.  One is to save memory (although this is more relevant when used in an array or other aggregate).  Another is to make it clear that it is intended to hold a `char` value.  Another is to implicitly restrict the range of its value.  And in some cases you may wish to take its address to obtain a `char *`, in which case you would not be able to use an `int` variable.