# Why do we have the type of char in C, if a character literal is always of type int? Isn´t the whole type of char in C redundant?

Tags: c, types, char, character, language-lawyer

As opposed to C++, In C, a character literal is implemented as to be always of type `int`.

---

But why we have then the type of `char` for holding a character value?

---

In the question [Why are C character literals ints instead of chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars),

it is discussed, *why* character literals are of type `int` in C. But this is not what my question is about.

Inside the question [If character constants are of type `int', why are they assigned to variables of type `char`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34192967/if-character-constants-are-of-type-int-why-are-they-assigned-to-variables-of) then it is going a little more into the deep with the question, why we actually assign character literals to variables of type `char` if they are of type `int`, but the provided answers left the concern, why we need the type of `char` in general.

---

My Questions are now:

- Why we have the type of `char` if any character literals are always of `int` type?
- Isn´t the type of `char` redundant then?
- What is the purpose of type `char`, if it is seemingly redundant?

Comment: How are you going to declare an array of characters if the type char will be absent?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The concept of the whole `char` type seems incorrect to me now. For me, the language had been needed to be defined different at this topic, to give a modifier or anything like that, to flag to the compiler that the context, if needed, is in regards to literal characters instead of to the usual integral values, by using `int` type.

Comment: Detail: "As opposed to C++, In C, a character constant ....".. C does not define  _character literal_.  In C, a _literal_ can have its address taken.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Ok, with the definition of *character literal* which is not made in the C standard, I understand. But I´ve thought literals are only hardcoded values. How they can have addresses?

Comment: The `char` type and a literal char constant are 2 separate entities, which dimensions are defined per the standard as the smallest memory unit available on the system, for the first, and as the standard `int` type for the second. Any tentative to make an equivalence between a `char` type and a char literal, i.e. `'abc'`, isn't formally correct.

Comment: A char can have different dimension on different machines, 8, 16 or even 32bits, and an assignment between a character literal and a `char` variable imply a type conversion from `int` to `char`.

Comment: [re](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59457398/why-do-we-have-the-type-of-char-in-c-if-a-character-literal-is-always-of-type-i?noredirect=1#comment105097298_59457398) In C, a _literal_ exists at some memory location, so it has an address.  Research _string literal_, _compound  literal_.  A constant like `'A'` need not exist at an address - e.g.  could be a value in the executable code.

Comment: "The concept of the whole char type seems incorrect to me now. " -- Millions of programmers think otherwise ... when beginning programmers ask a question, it's best for them to sit back and listen for a while before forming their own conclusions. "For me, the language had been needed to be defined different at this topic ..." -- It's hard to make sense of this and the rest of that sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just be cause a *character constant* in C source code has type `int` doesn't mean that the *type* `char` has no use.

The type `char` occupies 1 byte of space.  So you can use it anyplace where the values are in the range of a `char`, which includes ASCII characters.  You can read and write those characters from either the console or a file as single byte entities.  The fact that a character constant in source code has a different type doesn't change that.

Using `char` in an array also means you're using less memory than if you had an array of `int`, which can be useful in situations where space is at a premium.  This is especially true if you're using it as a binary format to store data on disk or send it over a network.

A `char *` can also be used to access the individual bytes of any object if you need to see how that object is represented.

Comment: ...but note that when a char is passed as an argument to a function, it is first turned into an int, probably because there is no machine that can place a single byte on the stack.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie From an ABI perspective yes, however from a *language* perspective a variable of type `char` passed to a function that expecting an argument of type `char` will not be converted.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie This is not true. Most 8-bit microcontrollers can place single bytes on stack and/or pass them as arguments using registers.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie "note that when a char is passed as an argument to a function, it is first turned into an int" -- that is only true if there's no prototype. If there's a prototype, then `char` may or may not take as many bytes on the stack as an `int`, depending on the calling sequence definition. "probably because there is no machine that can place a single byte on the stack" -- no, that isn't true and has nothing to do with why `char` and `short` are converted to `int` in the absence of a prototype. (And dbush's comment makes no sense.)

Comment: @dbush Is there a difference between character constants and ASCII characters? I´ve thought they would be the same.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica ASCII is a specific character encoding.  For example, ASCII maps the character `'A'` to the value 65, while EBCDIC maps `'A'` to 193.  Character constants in the C language map to whatever encoding the running system uses.

Answer (score 2):

The type char allows to address each byte (the smallest addressable unit of a CPU). So for example it allows to specify a memory extent of any  number of bytes for example for using in memcpy or memmove.

Also how to declare a character array without the type char?

If you declare it as an integer array when there will be redundant allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we have the type of `char` in C, if a character literal is always of type `int`?

`char, unsigned, char, signed char` are the minimal size object.  Character <strike>literal</strike> *constants* are type `int` for simplicity of the language and no strong need otherwise.  (C++ choose a different path - computers could handle more complex things 20 years later.)  There are no integer constants narrower than `int`.

> Isn't the whole type of `char` in C redundant?
>   Why we have the type of `char` if any character literals are always of `int` type?
>   Isn't the type of char redundant then?

No.  Object sizes benefit with a variety of sizes, constants less so.

> What is the purpose of type `char`, if it is seemingly redundant?

Concerning `int` and constants, `char` is not redundant. Concerning `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `char` is redundant  and reflects a compromise of early implementations of `char` as *unsigned* or *signed*.  This allows `char` to be *signed* (which is symmetric other integer type lacking `signed` or *unsigned* as conceptually characters are usually thought as.

---

Code can form a [compound literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Compound_literals) of type `char` if a  "char` literal" is needed.

```
char a = (char){'B'};
```