# Storing character in an integer variable

Tags: c

Confused, Why does this work when I compile, when hold is an integer?

```
char value = 'p';
int hold = value;
printf("%c", hold);
```

Comment: Do some researches about ASCII :)

Comment: `%c` of `printf` requires `int`. See [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: Since `'p'` is an integer, you really should be asking why `char value = 'p'` works!

Comment: still compiles with no warnings @iehrlich

Comment: ASCII value is 112 when I use %d, that I understand. But why does the compiler allow me store a character in an int and print it out as one? @Gam

Comment: An integer can store 4 or 8 bytes (depends on the OS), while a char is always 1 byte. So technically you can store a char into an int. Even if it's a char, in the memory it's just a numer (in binary). If you call printf( ) with the %c format, it means "please printf( ) print me the corresponding symbol of this number, with ASCII"

Comment: @Gam-- note that the C Standard does not specify that the character encoding be ASCII.

Comment: @DavidBowling That's right :)

Comment: `'p'` is an `int` in C, not `char` [Why are C character literals ints instead of chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/433895/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, in

```
int hold = value;
```

is performed implicit conversion from `char` to `int`.

Second, in

```
printf("%c", hold);
```

the `%c` specifier means something as *convert it to `char` and print it as symbol.*

Comment: The `%c` specifier tells `printf()` to _expect_ an argument of type `char`; no conversion is made (outside or the default argument promotions), and mismatched conversion specifiers and arguments cause undefined behavior. It is worth noting that `char` is an integer type.

Comment: @DavidBowling `%c` expect an argument of type `int`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY-- oops, you are correct; I haven't looked at this part of the Standard in a while, but just now I see that here an `int` is in fact converted to `unsigned char`.

Comment: Yes 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function p8 **c** If no l length modifier is present, the **int argument is converted to an
unsigned char**, and the resulting character is written.

Comment: "means something as convert it to char"  is _close_.  Better to incorporate [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44192417/storing-character-in-an-integer-variable#comment75399088_44192513)

Comment: When you call a function with an ellipsis at the end of its prototype (such as `print()`), all the arguments corresponding to the ellipsis undergo default promotions, so `float` values are converted to `double`, and types shorter than `int` are converted to `int`.  The wording in the standard is complex, but it means `char` is converted to `int` automatically as `printf()` is called.  That's why `printf()`'s specification says that `%c` prints an `int` converted to `unsigned char` as the character.