# In C, to convert character to an integer is it necessary to do typecast

Tags: c, typecast-operator

In C, is it necessary to typecast character to an integer when we are eventually going to subtract character 0 from a number character to get its equivalent figure in an integer?

The aim of the following examples is to convert character 5 to its equivalent figure in an integer.

```
char a = '5';
```

`int x = a - '0';` Here the decimal value of the character result obtained by subtracting character 0 from character 5 will be equivalent to character 5.

`int i = (int)a;` Here the decimal value of the character 5 will be assigned as it is even after doing typecast.

So what's the point of doing typecast when it shows no effect on its operand?

Comment: "the decimal value of the character result obtained by subtracting character 0 from character 5 will be equivalent to character 5" What?  The value obtained by subtracting the character `'0'` from `'5'` is `5` but the value of the character `'5'` is `53`. How is that equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion can be implicit (precision is not lost)

```
int x = a;
```

or explicit

```
int x = (int)a;
```

more exactly it is integer promotion and it is done before operation

```
int x = ((int)a) - '0';
```

in C '0' character literal is already int, whereas in C++ it is a char.

Comment: Character constants are already type `int`, so `'0'` is not promoted to `int`.

Comment: [character literals are `int` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/433895/995714), not `char`

Comment: Nitpick: "a cast" (ie "an explicit conversion") can never be implicit. What can be implicit or explicit are "conversions".

Answer (score 1):

> So what's the point of doing typecast when it shows no effect on its operand?

**Readability** of code (or conformance to the [C programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) specified in [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)).

BTW, most typecasts are not translated to any machine code by an [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler).