# C: Is a char possible between the square brackets of an array?

Tags: c, arrays, base64, character, square-bracket

Until today my answer would have been: "No, there has to be an integer in it, that determines the position of the array."

But now I got this code snippet (for base64-decoding) from our professor and I also found it here on stackoverflow and other internet sites:

```
static char encoding_table[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
                                'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
                                'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
                                'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
                                'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
                                'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
                                'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3',
                                '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/'};
static char *decoding_table = NULL;

void build_decoding_table1() {

    int i;
    decoding_table = malloc(256);

    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        decoding_table[(unsigned char) encoding_table[i]] = i;
}
```

The line, that surprises me, is:

```
decoding_table[(unsigned char) encoding_table[i]] = i;
```

What happens here -- at least I think that's what happens -- is that when for example `i` == `0`, we get the first position of the `encoding_table`-array, so `encoding_table[0]` == `'A'`. That gets casted to `unsigned char`, so it's still `'A'`. So we have: `decoding_table['A'] = 0;`

A char, that determines an array position is new to me. How does this work? Is the integer-equivalent of the ASCII-table used instead (`65` instead of `'A'`)? Or do I misunderstand, what this code does, and I'm outing me as a complete noob?

Comment: Yes, a char (or unsigned char in this case) is an integral type.  It can be used in the same ways as other integral types.

Comment: Yet this can be simply solved by defining the original array as unsigned...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are C character literals ints instead of chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars)

Comment: In C, 'A' is just a fancy way of writing the integer 65.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Literal `'A'` is - according to your system's character set, represented as an integral value, e.g. `65` in ASCII. BTW - the data type of the literal is `integer`, not `char`, but that does not matter much here.

Your encoding table is an array of `char`, and if your system's default is `signed char` for `char`, then the integral value 65 will be stored as a `signed char`, i.e. an 8 bit signed integral value.

The other way round, if you write `decoding_table[(unsigned char) encoding_table[i]]`, then the signed 8 bit integral value `65` from `encoding_table[i]` is casted to an unsigned 8 bit integral value, still giving `65`. Casting to unsigned is a good idea, since an 8 bit signed char might be negative, giving something like, for example, `decoding_table[-10]`. This would be undefined behaviour, since it accessed the array out of its bounds.

So you are assuming right: you may consider character literals as integral values, and hence you can use it as array index.

Comment: Yes, but by the time `encoding_table[i]` is used, the value is no longer `'A'`. That was used to initialise the array element.

Comment: @Weather Vane: yes, that's why `encoding_table[i]`gives a (likely signed) char value. Did I express it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need an integer for an array position, but a `char` is just an 8 bit integer.  Really, anything you can add to a pointer can be used in the brackets because `array[5]` is the same thing as `*(array+5)`.

Comment: You can add `-5` to a pointer. But `array[-5]` won't end well.

Comment: Also using (signed) `char` as index will lead to compiler warnings (well, gcc will warn)

Comment: `'a'` is an `int` type, not `char`. You can confirm this with `sizeof 'a'`

Comment: @WeatherVane In OP's code it is already char, as they are using the char array elements as index, not the literals.l

Comment: @EugeneSh. I only get warnings for pure `char`, not for `signed char` (using both gcc and clang)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was thrown off by OP's narrative `decoding_table['A'] = 0;` which isn't in the code itself.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Then probably it is more concerned about whether the programmer is actually aware of `char` signedness

Comment: @EugeneSh. Agreed.

Comment: Adding -5 to a pointer can also cause trouble if it's a pointer to the start of something.

Comment: Of course. Many things can cause troubles if used incorrectly. But using negative index in array will cause them always.

Comment: That's not actually true, but using negative indexes IS very bad coding practice because the array indexing syntax is almost always used with a pointer to the start of an array, which ends up being the same situation that I said before.