# Why sizeof() method is giving different results?

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

When I run the program below in C, I get the output result to be `4`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

//using namespace std;

int main()
{
    printf("%d", sizeof('a')); 
  return 0; 
}
```

But when I run the code below in C++, I get the output result to be `1`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    printf("%d", sizeof('a')); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Could you please explain why do I get different output for the same code as if `'a'` is the way we define characters in both the languages ?

Comment: *why do I get different output for the same code* -- C and C++ are two different languages, even though they are "almost" identical.  There are many other things that work one way in C++, but are different in C.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But I want to know the reason behind that.

Comment: @Kundan you mean the historical reason?

Comment: @Kundan See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars

Comment: Now you got it, yeah I want to know that @John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, a character representation (like `'a'`) has type `int`. So, `sizeof` operator returns the size of an integer.

In C++, it's of a character type.

Comment: please vote to close obvious dupes.

Comment: @Kundan: character literals such as `'a' ` have a data type just like numeric literals such as `1` and `2.3` have data types. The type of character literals in C is `int` while in C++, it's `char`

Comment: @machine_1 C calls `'a'` a _constant_ - not a _literal_.  C's literals (like `"a"`) can have their address taken,  Cannot do `&'a'` in C.