# why I can't declare variables on the fly while making the conditions in the for loop as an example?

Tags: c, for-loop

I had made this code that iterate through the alphabets using their ascii code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for ( int alphabet = (int) char A = 'A'; alphabet <= (int) char Z = 'Z'; alphabet++) {
        printf("The number of the Alphabet %c is %d\n ",(char) alphabet , alphabet  );
    }
}
```

but upon compiling it just say that it is expected to have an expression before **char A** or **char B** which I don't really understand what does that mean
so any help will be appreciated xD

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. Perhaps you meant `for ( int alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z'; alphabet++)`

Comment: You cannot assign two declarations + you cannot declare a variable inside the `for` loop condition block. This is the proper way: `for (int alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z'; alphabet++) {`

Comment: But I thought that I need to typecast the 'A' character before assigning it to the alphabet variable... How it can just treat it as integer if it's not ?

Comment: @MahmoudSalah, google for *c type casting* - https://www.guru99.com/c-type-casting.html

Comment: A character literal like `'A'` is an int. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars Even if it wasn't you wouldn't need the cast. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion

Comment: @RetiredNinja so to insure that my understanding is right.... just the c language that treats the char as int numbers ? so if i would to make the same program in c++ i would need to actually typecasting it before making that assignment to the variable alphabet  right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define identifiers like `(int) char A = 'A'` to represent characters.

Just simply do:

```
for (int alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z'; alphabet++)
    printf("The number of the Alphabet %c is %d\n", alphabet, alphabet);
```

Notice that you don't need to use `(char)` in the `printf()`, it automatically converts into the character from the integer. Also, you don't need to use curly-braces for single syntax in loops & conditions, **it's recommended to do** to avoid confusions their ending scopes.

Comment: so to insure that my understanding is right.... just the c language that treats the char as int numbers ? so if i would to make the same program in c++ i would need to actually typecasting it before making that assignment to the variable alphabet right ?

Comment: @MahmoudSalah the chars are actually integers in ASCII type. Suppose, the char 'A', it's equal to integer 65 in ASCII. You still don't need to typecast explicitly in C++ too.

Comment: "Also, you don't need to use curly-braces for single syntax in loops & conditions." - but it is recommended and  in most coding conventions it is even required.

Comment: @MahmoudSalah a `char` is a type of integer, just like `int`, `long`, or the fixed-width types `uint8_t`, `int16_t` etc. It is however a little bit special, in that the signedness is implementation defined, which means that it might be signed on one platform but unsigned on another.

Comment: @RohanBari: In C, characters are encoded as integers, but not necessarily ASCII. Many C implementations use ASCII, but you should not teach people to assume that.