# What does `::` do in C++ language?

Tags: c++

I found a C++ file in PARSEC benchmark suite and saw some functions like this:

```
long Rng::rand()
{
    return _rng->randInt();
}
```

what does the `::` in the name of the function do here?

Comment: That is not C, but C++

Comment: This does indeed look like a C++ method definition rather than a C function. Are you sure it was C code and not C++?

Comment: I'm sorely tempted to rollback the edits by [devnull](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2235132/devnull) and [Randy Howard](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2159730/randy-howard) since they completely rewrite the question.  The original question was about `::` in C; it has been revised so that C is no longer a tag or mentioned in the question, which makes my answer immaterial (because it addresses the original, C question and not the revised, C++ question).  Edits are fine when they keep the intent of the original question.  They aren't when they don't.

Answer (score 10):

In C++ `::` is the **[Scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator)**.
In this case it tells the compiler that it is a defintiion for `rand()` method which is a member function for `Rng` class/structure/union/namespace.

Comment: Given that `C` does not have `class`es, can you clarify your statement beginning with "In this case..."?

Comment: @Shredderroy: The Q is tagged C++.

Comment: +1, but `Rng` could also be a namespace.

Comment: @juanchopanza: True that.

Comment: Note that although this is the name for `::`, it's not an operator like the others. It doesn't operate on subexpressions. It joins *identifiers* to form *qualified-ids*, which are just more-specific names for things. So you could say it's "just" a punctuator, more like `;` than `+`.

Answer (score 10):

In C, `::` is a syntax error unless it occurs inside a comment, a character literal or a string literal.

The `::` can only appear in C++ code.

Comment: How can `::` appear inside a *character* literal? Am I missing something?

Comment: @H2CO3 And that isn't a syntax error? Two characters inside single quotes?

Comment: @yzt [nope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/c-multicharacter-literal)

Comment: Multi-character character constants have an implementation-defined value, so they are not portable, but they are legitimate.  See [Does anyone know of a C compiler that fails to compile this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328215/does-anyone-know-of-a-c-compiler-that-fails-to-compile-this) for an extreme example.

Comment: Note that character literals/constants in C are actually ints - hence why older functions like getc, fgetc etc return ints, and functions like toupper and putc take ints instead of chars... Win32 programming makes heavy use of it with people giving things like timers and events integer values formed from four-character constants: `mainWnd->StartTimer('BEEP');`.