# Using variable for switch case statement

Tags: c

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int var=1, x=1, y=2;
    switch(var)
    {
        case 'x':
            x++;
            break;
        case 'y':
            y++;
            break;
    }
    printf("%d %d",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

here I am not getting the required output
Can anyone explain it why ?

My Expected output is : 2,2

Comment: `var` is not `x` or `y`, it's `1`. What would your expected output be?

Comment: but x has value 1, so why i m not getting the output 2,2

Comment: What is the required output?

Comment: 2,2 is the required output

Comment: why's this question being downvoted? what's wrong with it?

Comment: @Chaos Maybe because someone didn't read their K&R C book? (not my downvote, btw).

Comment: @Jens, the question is well formed, shows effort and it's obvious OP has misunderstood the concept, I personally don't think it deserves downvotes

Comment: @Chaos Well-formed with quite a bit of community contribution. Check the revision history, specifically the original post. I would have downvoted that too.

Comment: @gg_s Oh wow, did not see that ! Yep, I get it now

Comment: @AmanSingh: you should ask a new question instead of completely rewriting the old one, because now the comments and the answers make no sense at all.

Comment: I am not allowed to ask new question because of a number of downvotes in a silly question that's why i have edited the previous one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a switch statement (in C), you can't use variables in `case`. You must use constant.

And also, `case 'x':` do not refer to the variable `x` but to a constant `'x'` who is a char. You are not testing what you seem to want... In this case, you are testing `case 121:`, where 121 is the ascii code for the letter 'x'.

You can solve your problem with something like :

```
# include <stdio.h>

#define INIT_X 1
#define INIT_Y 2
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

int main(void)
{
    int var=1, x=INIT_X, y=INIT_Y;
    //         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    switch(var)
    {
        case INIT_X:
        //   ^^^^^^
            x++;
            break;
        case INIT_Y:
        //   ^^^^^^
            y++;
            break;
    }
    printf("%d %d",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Got ya,  Thank u Pierre for ur help

Answer (score 8):

You misunderstand the `switch` statement.

The switch statement compares the expression (often a simple variable) in the `switch (expression)` with a series of distinct compile-time constant values in the various `case` labels, and executes the code after that label.  If the value does not match any of the explicit `case` labels, then the `default` label is used if it is present, or the whole `switch` is skipped if there is no `default` label.

In your code, you have `var` set to `1`.  Neither `case 'x':` nor `case 'y':` matches `1` (they'd be equivalent to `case 120:` and `case 121:` in most codesets based on ASCII), and there is no `default`, so the `switch` is skipped, and the output is `1 2` (not, as you appear to have expected, `2 2`).

> What is a compile-time constant?

The values in the case labels must be determinable by the compiler as the code is compiled, and must be constant expressions.  That means that the expressions in the case labels cannot refer to variables or functions, but they can use basic computations on fixed (integral) values.

Given:

```
#include <math.h>
const int x = 3;               // C++ compilers treat this differently
enum { BIG_TIME = 60 };
#define HOURS(x) (3600 * (x))

case sin(x):     // Invalid - function of a variable
case x:          // Invalid - variable
case sin(0.0):   // Invalid - function
case 'x':        // Valid - character constant
case 'xy':       // Valid but not portable
case BIG_TIME:   // Valid - enumeration value names are constant
case HOURS(2):   // Valid - expands to (3600 * (2)) which is all constant
```

Comment: Can you please explain about the compile-time constant ?

Comment: and if i use just x and y instead of 'x' and 'y' ?

Comment: It will not be a C valid expression even if some compiler will accept that.

Comment: Is your `case 'xy':` valid ? It seems that you did a mistake here. At least you will end with a warning like : `warning: multi-character character constant`... But your are right, it is a constant ;)

Comment: It is valid, but the interpretation of multi-character constants is implementation-defined.

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud: Life got in the way of editing the previous comment... It (a multi-character constant) is valid, but the interpretation of multi-character constants is implementation-defined.  GCC chooses to generate the warning almost always.  See also [Does anyone know of a C compiler that fails to compile this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328215/does-anyone-know-of-a-c-compiler-that-fails-to-compile-this/).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use variables in a `case` as the values must be compile-time constants. Also your code is incorrect as `'x'` and `'y'` are constants (literals), and hence do not refer to the variables `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 2):

using 'x' in quotes is actually using the constant ASCII code value for the character x, which is actually number value 120 (according to the ASCII chart).  It does not use the variable you declared.