# expressin is not an integer constant expression

Tags: ios, objective-c, switch-statement

I am using `switch case` into my method like in screenshot

[image]

I already done with **`Enumeration`** but how can I directly pass **`int constant`** into case??

I googled it but I found it with Enumeration
Please help me with it

Comment: post code instead of image.

Comment: That is Objective-C,  not Swift.

Comment: @KAR This is my only code into image

Comment: The C language just doesn't allow it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580985/using-variable-for-switch-case-statement or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139757/switch-in-c-programming or other questions about `[c] switch expression not constant`.

Answer (score 0):

If that's all the functionality you want to achieve then you should write something like this:

```
if (index.row == value) {
    // logic when it's that row
} else {
    // default case
}
```

What you tried to do is simply not possible, see the two questions linked by Martin R in the comments.